# Print a specific value in the infinite Walsh matrix

Tags: code-golf, binary-matrix

The [Walsh matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_matrix) is an interesting fractal matrix with the property that every single value in a Walsh matrix has a value of either -1 or 1. Additionally, the size of a Walsh matrix is always a power of 2.

Because each Walsh matrix is identical to the top-left quarter of the immediately higher-order Walsh matrix, we can create a generalized "infinite Walsh matrix" by considering the limit of the sequence of Walsh matrices of order N, as N goes to infinity. From here on, we will call this infinite generalization *the Walsh matrix*.

Your task is to build a program that takes the coordinates of a location in the Walsh matrix and returns the value that occurs there.

Your program will accept two integers `x` and `y` as input (in any form you choose), and output the value that appears in the `x+1`th row of the `y+1`th column of the Walsh matrix. For example, the input

```
2 5
```

will return `1`, as the 3rd row in the 6th column of the Walsh matrix has a value of 1. The input

```
6 4
```

will return `-1`, as the 7th row in the 5th column of the Walsh matrix has a value of -1. The input

```
2834719 394802
```

will return `-1`, as the 2384720th row of the 394803rd column has a value of -1.

The shortest code to do this in any language wins.

Comment: I quickly figured out a procedure for determining the value of any cell.  Problem is, it only gives the correct answer half of the time. :)

Comment: `print "0 ± 1"`

Comment: @DavidCarraher, it seems that if you output `1` you'll do better than 50%.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, Great idea, and your solution even saves a few characters.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Of course, the limit as you go to infinity is still 50%.

Comment: Please add a minimal description of the matrix so that the problem makes sense when wikipedia is down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GolfScript (<strike>18 15</strike> 14 bytes)

```
~&2base-1\0-,?
```

Takes input space-separated; outputs to stdout. Thanks to [Howard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1490/howard) for pointing out that the space in the 15-char solution was removable.

The way I reasoned to this solution is quite simple. Take the highest set bit of `x|y`: this tells you the size of the smallest Walsh matrix which contains the relevant index. Then clearing that bit in both `x` and `y` drops us down to the top-left quadrant, and we need to multiply by `-1` if we were previously in the bottom-right quadrant: i.e. if the bit was set in both `x` and `y`. By induction down the bit sequence, we just need to count the number of bits set in `x&y`.

Comment: Of course it is much shorter to write `~&2base-1\0-,?`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 44 bytes

```forth
: f and 1e 63 for s>d 2* 1+ s>f f* 2* next ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVDLbsIwELz7K@bCxVGo1wmQEClf0guVY@BAUiWW2r8P9joqgSIetuTHeGZ3xrbr3SHd27CNW1jsWgOF4Wf3jXUGj/ub0RKnBG3z65BA49QZeIgiLUUlXlGm1MDUFlbKmYKuFBofoXjadw6q5iYJZKRwkZlwicB6ZnLuzhu4oh8tm7IS7tC0tw3ezxJQddNjCKxJ9Sj5UBvOM4X1yilJNf63H8jxb7i8/KNX44KIFM/L4jexIL75QZcXRb60XeITJb6ObhDP1eqeuohqobFiSKyRx4MusnxDJbIyL5RmbDwD)

The function takes two word-sized unsigned integers (64 bits on TIO). It returns -1 or 1 on the floating-point stack and leaves a garbage 0 on the main stack.

The algorithm follows [Blckknght's submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20953/78410), but the task made me explore LOTS of possibilities for writing Forth programs - from bit shift, divmod, single-to-double conversion to abusing floating-point stack. (The TIO link has several alternative definitions of `f` which all work, but are longer than the main answer.)

#### How it works

```forth
: f ( u1 u2 -- -1e_or_1e )  \ Takes two integers and returns a float 1 or -1
  and 1e                    \ Bitwise and(=N), then put a 1(=R) on the FP stack
  63 for                    \ Repeat 64 times... (TIO gforth has 64-bit cells)
    s>d                       \ Sign-extend single N to double
                              \ In effect, 0 is pushed if MSB is zero, -1 otherwise
    2* 1+ s>f f*              \ Change 0_or_-1 to 1_or_-1, cast to float and multiply with R
    2*                        \ Shift N left once
  next                      \ End loop
  ;                         \ End function
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 - 42 bytes

```
print(-1)**bin(input()&input()).count("1")
```

This takes the two coordinates as separate lines on standard input and writes the answer to standard output.

The algorithm is this:

1. For coordinates `X` and `Y`, find `X & Y`, the bitwise AND of their values.
2. Count the number of 1 bits in `X & Y`. This is the number of times the requested coordinate is in the bottom right quadrant of a level of the matrix.
3. If the count is odd, the result is -1. If the count is even, the result is 1.

This should work for any positive integer coordinates (including large ones that need more than 32 bits).

Answer (score 1):

## x86_64 machine language for Linux, 17 bytes

```
0x00:  48 21 F7          and    rdi, rsi
0x03:  F3 48 0F B8 C7    popcnt rax, rdi
0x08:  FF C0             inc    eax
0x0a:  24 01             and    al, 1
0x0c:  01 C0             add    eax, eax
0x0e:  FF C8             dec    eax
0x10:  C3                ret
```

Same algorithm as @Blckknght's answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYrRCsIgGIXvewwh0HDgr9Ycozfxxv7mGDWJtgspevVM260Xh3POx4fNiJgSPXhG2ZnYqI2NEmz0bY7avvA2XnJjYXmjyI7OHLaU/@fFUaRPs5sCZe/d4zmF1VOyv9pAuKeCC8b6CoYahroNdVvyYw2fuK7aRukWOq46bYQsxid90d/duKTmNcQBl9Xh7Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

-2 bytes by converting to tacit form

```
-:/[;1]@+/&/+2\,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYxCoAgFADQ3VOYRQ5m5tfKdOkeJjTZEPw5iM5uNb13SjywlOylVzHotArVKgFbV3KEMCaS4xTsDzhjZ70Es1g3QCI7HTyjTPFbQv2lux7OG6wz7bmo0Dvqygs)

Based off of [@Blckknght's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20953/98547).

- `&/+2\,` take the (equivalent of) the bitwise-and of x and y
- `+/` do a popcnt (i.e. number of bits set to 1)
- `-:/[;1]@` negate `1` that many times and return