# Find a point's position on the integral Hilbert curve

Tags: code-golf

The Hilbert curves are a class of space-filling fractal curves where every bend in the path is at a right angle and the curve as a whole fills up a square, with the property that sequences of consecutive segments are always displayed as contiguous blocks.

Traditionally, the curve is drawn as a series of very squiggly lines inside a square such that each segment becomes smaller and smaller until they fill up the whole square. However, like the [Walsh matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/print-a-specific-value-in-the-infinite-walsh-matrix), it is also possible to represent the limit curve as a sequence of line segments connecting lattice points that grows infinitely until it fills up an entire quadrant of lattice points on the Cartesian plane.

Suppose we define such a curve as the *integral Hilbert curve*, as follows:

- Start at the origin.
- Move one unit right (`R`), one unit up (`U`), and one unit left (`L`). Down will be notated as `D`.
- Let `RUL` be `H_1`. Then define `H_2` as `H_1 U I_1 R I_1 D J_1` where:

  - `I_1` is `H_1` rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise and flipped horizontally.
  - `J_1` is `H_1` rotated 180 degrees.

  Perform the steps of `H_2` after `H_1` to complete `H_2`.
- Define `H_3` as `H_2 R I_2 U I_2 L J_2`, where:

  - `I_2` is `H_2` rotated 90 degrees clockwise and flipped vertically.
  - `J_2` is `H_2` rotated 180 degrees.

  Perform the steps of `H_3` after `H_2` to complete `H_3`.
- Define `H_4` and other `H_n` for even `n` the same way as `H_2`, but relative to `H_{n-1}`.
- Define `H_5` and other `H_n` for odd `n` the same way as `H_3`, but relative to `H_{n-1}`.
- The integral Hilbert curve is `H_infinity`.

We get a function `f(n) = (a, b)` in this way, where `(a, b)` is the position of a point moving `n` units along the integral Hilbert curve starting from the origin. You may notice that if we draw this curve `2^{2n}-1` units long we get the `n`th iteration of the unit-square Hilbert curve magnified `2^n` times.

Your task is to implement `f(n)`. The shortest code to do so in any language wins.

---

Example inputs and outputs:

```
> 0
(0, 0)
> 1
(1, 0)
> 9
(2, 3)
> 17
(4, 1)
> 27
(6, 3)
> 41
(7, 6)
> 228
(9, 3)
> 325
(24, 3)
```

Note that your solution's *algorithm* must work in general; if you choose to implement your algorithm in a language where integers are of bounded size, that bound must not be a factor in your program's code.

Comment: By your last line, do you mean that if we are implementing the iterative approach of the algorithm, we should not have while (s<INT_MAX) in the loop ?

Comment: No, I mean your code shouldn't have a top-down approach that assumes a maximum size. If you need an INT_MAX checker for stability, you can assume that you will never receive input that would trigger that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### GolfScript (62 bytes)

```
{1:a:b(.@4base{:?3%!:|b^?2<3?=.b^:b^^|!.a^:a^{\}*{@2*@+}2*}/\}
```

This is an anonymous function which takes `n` on the stack and leaves `x y` on the stack. [Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IyMKOycwCjEKOQoxNwoyNwo0MQoyMjgKMzI1J24ve34KIyMKCnsxOmE6YiguQDRiYXNlezo%2FMyUhOnxiXj8yPDM%2FPS5iXjpiXl58IS5hXjphXntcfSp7QDIqQCt9Mip9L1x9CgojIwp%2BXXB9LwojIw%3D%3D)

It's essentially the iterative code from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve#Applications_and_mapping_algorithms) reversed so that it processes the base-4 representation of `n` from most-significant to least-significant digit instead of least-significant to most-significant. This simplifies the bookkeeping required to output `x` and `y` in the right order.

Pseudocode translation (not tested, may contain errors):

```
a = b = true;
x = y = 0;
foreach (digit in n base 4) {
    p = (digit % 3 == 0) ^ b;
    q = (digit < 2) ^ b;
    b ^= (digit == 3);
    if (a) swap(p, q);
    a ^= (digit % 3 != 0);
    y = 2*y + (p ? 1 : 0);
    x = 2*x + (q ? 1 : 0);
    swap(x, y);
}
swap(x, y)
```

Answer (score 3):

### R: <s>178</s> 169

Room for improvement in this, but it's a start

```
f=function(d){x=y=0;s=1;while(s<Inf){a=bitwAnd(1,d/2);b=bitwAnd(1,bitwXor(d,a));if(b==0){if(a==1){x=s-1-x;y=s-1-y};t=x;x=y;y=t};x=x+(s*a);y=y+(s*b);d=d/4;s=s*2};c(x,y)}
```

Test Run

```
> f(0)
[1] 0 0
> f(1)
[1] 1 0
> f(9)
[1] 2 3
> f(41)
[1] 7 6
> f(325)
[1] 24  3
```