# Is this number evil?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem, number-theory

## Introduction

In number theory, a number is considered evil if there are an even number of 1's in its binary representation. In today's challenge, you will be identifying whether or not a given number is evil.

## Challenge

Your job is to write a full program or function which accepts a single, non-negative integer as input and outputs (or returns) whether or not that number is evil.

- You may output any [truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey#2194) value if the number is evil, and any falsy value if the number is not evil.
- You may input and output in [any acceptable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.
- [OEIS sequence A001969](https://oeis.org/A001969) is the sequence containing all evil numbers.
- [Here](https://oeis.org/A001969/b001969.txt) is a list of the first 10000 evil numbers, for reference (and more test cases!)
- This question is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shorter, the better.
- Don't be put off by extremely short answers in golfing languages. I encourage you to submit in any language you like.
- Here are some test cases:

  ```
  3 => True
  11 => False
  777 => True
  43 => True
  55 => False
  666 => False
  ```

### The Leaderboard

At the bottom of the page is a stack snippet containing a leaderboard for this question. (Thanks, @MartinEnder)

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 169724; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 81420; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [],
  answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1,
  more_answers = true,
  comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];

  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if (OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });

    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    //else console.log(body);
  });

  valid.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
      bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function(a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;

    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
      .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
      .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
      .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
      .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>' + lang + '</a>').text();

    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {
      lang: a.language,
      lang_raw: lang,
      user: a.user,
      size: a.size,
      link: a.link
    };
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() > b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() < b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
      .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
      .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
      .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block !important;
}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/all.css?v=ffb5d0584c5f">
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Language</td>
        <td>User</td>
        <td>Score</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td>Language</td>
        <td>Size</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr>
      <td>{{PLACE}}</td>
      <td>{{NAME}}</td>
      <td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td>
      <td>{{SIZE}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr>
      <td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td>
      <td>{{NAME}}</td>
      <td>{{SIZE}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*EDIT: I believe this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/count-the-number-of-ones-in-an-unsigned-16-bit-integer), because whereas that question is asking to count the number of ones, this question is asking whether the number of ones is even. Although you **can** accomplish this question by simply counting the bits, there are [other approaches too](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169729/81420).*

Comment: [Sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16722/81420)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/162116/52210) (XOR-ing every binary digit is the same as taking the sum modulo-2).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the number of ones in an unsigned 16-bit integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/count-the-number-of-ones-in-an-unsigned-16-bit-integer)

Comment: My language (R) only has 32-bit signed integers; beyond that it switches by default to a `double`; is it OK if we run out of precision?

Comment: @Giuseppe no problem, as long as your program works for 32 bits you're fine.

Comment: @BetaDecay I have tried to address that above. I personally don't think this is a duplicate though.

Comment: This is a dupe because you can take any of those answers and bolt mod 2 on the end

Comment: @BetaDecay but that doesn't work in reverse: i.e. you cannot take all of these answers and remove the mod 2. Therefore, this challenge invites some new methods.

Comment: @BetaDecay side note: is there meta consensus as to what constitutes a duplicate?

Comment: A challenge is a dupe if a trivial change can be made to answers of the original challenge to make them suitable for the duplicate challenge. Backwards compatibility is AFAIK not counted

Comment: @BetaDecay is there anywhere on meta that says that or not? Also, if this really is a dupe, what should I do? I still think this challenge can invite some different approaches.

Comment: Quick question: does the output need to be true/false or can it be 1/0?

Comment: @RobertS. any two values that are considered truthy and falsy in your language are fine.

Comment: Related: [How on earth did llhuii output the Evil Numbers in 42 bytes of Python?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144017)

Comment: I believe that `666 => False` should be a test case.

Comment: @JoKing if by broken you mean the random HTML at the bottom, that's due to misformatted answers. I've tried to edit or comment on all of those.

Comment: Why would you call this an "evil" number. There is a long standing tradition to declare the binary representation of the number as being "even parity".

Comment: @user2390246 finally, done. ;)

Comment: Leaderboard says `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined", "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js", "lineno": 122, "colno": 18"`

Comment: @SimonForsberg sorry, that doesn't happen for me...i don't know why it's happening for you.

Comment: @Amphibological I found out why, I'm getting "too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 57696 seconds" back from the Stack Exchange API. I think I know [who to blame](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51786/duga?tab=profile) though.

Comment: Yes, 666 is not evil, but 616 is. More evidence corroborating Papyrus 115!

Comment: Someone needs to upvote this post so it's at 43 upvotes (an evil number)

Comment: Awaiting answer in evil

Comment: If a number has an equal number of ones in binary and decimal, is that double evil?

Answer (score 38):

## Z80 Assembly (8-bit), 2 bytes

The following code only works with values up to 255:

```
; Input is given in register A.
; P flag is set if A is evil.
B7     or A
C9     ret
```

---

## 16-bit version (works on all test cases), 3 bytes

This works with values up to 65535.

```
; Input is given in BC.
; Output is the same as above.
78     ld A,B
A9     xor C
C9     ret
```

If you're feeling adventurous, you can shave off 1 byte by storing the input in `A` and `C` like so

```
      ld BC, 777
C5    push BC
F1    pop AF
```

and then running

```
A9    xor C
C9    ret
```

However, this puts the burden on the caller, so it may be that the two bytes (`push BC` and `pop AF`) should be counted as well.

Comment: i like this but how does this work?  my memory for assembly (6502 + arm) are that `or`s are bitwise with 2 operands

Comment: @northern-bradley: The P flag is the parity of the OR result, i.e. the horizontal-xor of all the bits, i.e. popcnt mod 2.  [x86 also has a parity flag (PF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_flag), but it's updated only from the low byte of the result even for wider operand-sizes like `test eax,eax`.  So for x86 you'd probably `popcnt eax, edi` / `and eax,1` / `ret`.  (Fun fact: 8086 was designed to make source porting of 8080 asm trivial / doable by a machine.  [The start of x86: Intel 8080 vs Intel 8086?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6500).)

Comment: For x86-16, we can `xor al,ah` / `ret` (return value in PF), taking advantage of the same hardware feature in x86.  I [wrote this up as an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/169724/is-this-number-evil/169903#169903).

Comment: Is `P` allowed as per https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8509/29560? It's a single bit within the `F` (flags) register which has only three pairs of instructions affected by it. Also, this answer fails to mention it's only competing for 8-bit values, since `A` is an 8-bit register. This means it is unable to give an answer for `777`, or any other unsigned value over 255.

Comment: Damn built-ins `:P`

Comment: @cschultz2048 `A` is paired with `F`, so I wouldn't accept `AB` or `BA` as a 16-bit value. `BC` is 16-bit, but then you need an extra instruction to load one of them into `A` before XORing the other. I've always just mentioned that my Z80 answers work fully up to 255 or 65535, depending on the question. Maybe add a 16-bit version as well? So 2 bytes for 8-bit values, 3 bytes for 16-bit values.

Answer (score 32):

## JavaScript (ES6), 18 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?!f(n&~-n):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCoMwEEbhq@hGZ0AH3Rai9BylSLCJRNJ/JEqhm1492s2Db/NW@7H7nMJ2tNCXy9kbmAFj6QnVrwXf@jwrdo1Ooi70EJF7SvZLfdfxU952I5qaAlyY4ar4EA@XCH9eD2ZZNYDqpmbOJw)

#### Explanation

The bitwise logic goes like this:

- For integers, `~-n` is equivalent to `-(-n)-1`, so that just another way of doing `n-1`. In that particular case, we could actually have used `n-1`.
- `n & (n-1)` removes the least significant bit set to **1** in **n** because decrementing **n** turns all trailing **0**'s into **1**'s and clears the **1** that immediately follows (by carry propagation), while leaving everything else unchanged.

  **Example for n = 24 (11000 in binary):**

  ```
    11000 (24)                  11000 (24)
  -     1                   AND 10111 (23)
  -------                   ---------
  = 10111 (23)              =   10000 (16)
     ^                           ^
     |                           |
     +--- this bit is cleared ---+
  ```

Therefore, we process as many recursive calls as there are **1**'s in the binary representation of **n**, inverting the result each time with `!`. The last call always returns **1**.

**Examples:**

```
f(24) = !f(16) = !!f(0) = !!1 = true
f(7) = !f(6) = !!f(4) = !!!f(0) = !!!1 = false
```

Comment: Hello, I understand what the code does, but I just cannot figure out the logic/reasoning behind it, despite having read several articles about bitwise operations, checking if a number is a power of 2, etc. I know what a recursive function is. I just don't get why it has been used this way and why this works to answer to the puzzle, i.e. the link between the recursion and !f(power of two) <==> evil number. If you have time, explanation would be welcome :) thanks!

Comment: @supafly I've added an explanation. And BTW: welcome to PPCG!

Comment: The processing is very clear now. Still, the idea/reasoning is really magic! Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 19):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda n:int(bin(n),13)%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjOvRCMpM08jT1PH0FhT1eg/V1p@kUJJanGJQmaegoaxjoKhoY6Cubm5joIJkGNqqmnFxVlQBNSmkKYBUqb5HwA)

`bin(n)` gives a result like `'0b10101'`. Reading this as a base-13 integer, we get

$$ \color{red}{11\cdot13^5} + 1\cdot13^4 + 0\cdot13^3 + 1\cdot13^2 + 0\cdot13^1 + 1\cdot13^0 $$
which reduces modulo 2 to
$$\equiv \color{red}{1 \color{pink}{\cdot 1^5}} + 1 \color{#aaa}{\cdot 1^4} + 0 \color{#aaa}{\cdot 1^3} + 1\color{#aaa}{\cdot 1^2} + 0\color{#aaa}{\cdot 1^1} + 1\color{#aaa}{\cdot 1^0} \pmod 2 $$
$$\equiv \color{red}{1}+1+0+1+0+1 \pmod 2.$$

So `int(bin(n),13)%2` equals 1 + (number of ones in `bin(n)`) modulo 2.

If `n` is evil, then the result is 1; otherwise it is 0.

I picked up this trick from [Noodle9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144017/how-on-earth-did-llhuii-output-the-evil-numbers-in-42-bytes-of-python?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment353104_144027).

Answer (score 14):

## Japt `-h!`, <s>5</s> <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
¤å^
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=pOVe&input=NjY2Ci1oIQ==)

---

### Explanation

```
¤       :Convert to base-2 string
 å^     :Cumulatively reduce by XORing
        :Implicitly output the last element negated
```

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, porting Kevin's 05AB1E solution also works out at 5 bytes, if you want to try for that.

Comment: `¤¬x v` this is kevin's answer

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, yup, that's it.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
bSOÈ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/Kdj/cMf//@bm5gA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/pGD/wx3/df5HG@soGBrqKJibm@somAA5pqaxAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
b       # Convert to binary string
        #  i.e. 777 → 1100001001
 S      # Change it to a list of 0s and 1s
        #  i.e. 1100001001 → ['1','1','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1']
  O     # Take the sum
        #  i.e. ['1','1','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1'] → 4
   È    # Check if it's even (1 as truthy, 0 as falsey)
        #  i.e. 4 → 1
```

Comment: Alternatively: `b1¢È`

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>37</s> 26 bytes

```r
!sum(scan()%/%2^(0:31))%%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X7G4NFejODkxT0NTVV/VKE7DwMrYUFNTVdXov7m5@X8A)

An alternative to [Robert S.'s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169731/67312), this eschews the built-in bit splitting <s>but ends up less golfy</s> and thanks to JayCe and digEmAll ends up coming in slightly golfier.

Only works for positive integers less than \$2^{31}-1\$.

Comment: Why don't hardcode 31 instead of log2 ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0JTsbg0V6NCVV/VKE7DwMrYUFNTVdXof5qGsSZXmoahIYg0NzcHUSZgIVNTzf8A "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @digEmAll Which in turn means [no need to define x](https://tio.run/##K/r/X7G4NFejODkxT0NTVV/VKE7DwMrYUFNTVdXov7m5@X8A)

Comment: @digEmAll thanks! I wasn't sure about precision issues, although I suppose that past \$2^{31}-1\$ we (probably) lose precision in the `%/%` and `%%` operators so it would be a moot point.

Comment: Also intToBits supports only integer values up to 2^31-1 ;)

Answer (score 8):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>43</s> 38 bytes

---

**Golfed** [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9BC4JAEIXP7a8YpGAXTNASIdNDQRAEQQUdqoNsay3UbLhrl/C326IZQXOZYd68jzdcD7mW9aJEPl2iGQUuzJS6iQxTyCGpZZLOFT5FYbyd2ppC4oVKN2DetrxTnqScDYKpX8ekRxr74QRGaDPPtNCQwIuArZHbNN9vexRF7TD@CGHoksoieiRXhcj4lUID@6JA4g@WfbA2mLZRvX0hjaDQd6zrUZoJvLrb6ojr0rS7nHZbVjnA4n/ESqKgzhEdK1b2oU7ciOzcaCyu3w)

```cs
i=>Convert.ToString(i,2).Sum(c=>c)%2<1
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
i => Convert.ToString( i, 2 ).Sum( c => c ) % 2 < 1
```

---

**Full code** with tests

```cs
Func<Int32, Boolean> f = i => Convert.ToString( i, 2 ).Sum( c => c ) % 2 < 1;

Int32[] testCases = { 3, 11, 777, 43, 55 };

foreach( Int32 testCase in testCases ) {
    Console.Write( $" Input: {testCase}\nOutput: {f(testCase)}" );
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.1** - `-5 bytes` - Replaced `Count` to `Sum`
- **v1.0** - `43 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

**Notes**

- None

Comment: Upvoted for the chuckle your "ungolfed" version gave me.

Answer (score 8):

## Bash (no external utilities), <s>56</s> 44 bytes

<s>`while(($1));do set $(($1/2)) $(($2+$1%2));done;!(($2%2))`</s>

```
(($1))&&exec $0 $[$1/2] $[$2+$1%2];!(($2%2))
```

This assumes that the number is found in `$1`, having been passed as the first command line argument. It also assumes that this is a shell script (so that it can `exec` itself).

It recurses, after a fashion, using `exec $0`, until the number (in `$1`) reaches zero, dividing it by two in each iteration. It also sums (in `$2`) the number of times we get a number that is odd.  At the end, the original number was "evil" if the sum in `$2` in not odd.

Example invocations:

```
$ ./script 3 && echo evil
evil

$ ./script 11 && echo evil

$ ./script 777 && echo evil
evil

$ ./script 43 && echo evil
evil

$ ./script 55 && echo evil
```

For `0`:

```
$ ./script 0 && echo evil
./script: line 1: ((: %2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%2")
evil
```

Correct result, with a bit of extra on the side.

Answer (score 7):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
:1|e
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3A1%7Ce&i=3%0A11%0A777%0A43%0A55&a=1&m=2)

```
:1|e Full program, implicit input-evaluation
:1   Count set bits
  |e Check if even
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>99</s> <s>98</s> <s>44</s> <s>34</s> 28 bytes

-1 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen! -54 thanks to ngm! -10 thanks to Giuseppe! -6 thanks to JayCe!

```r
!sum(intToBits(scan())>0)%%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X7G4NFcjM68kJN8ps6RYozg5MU9DU9POQFNV1ei/qel/AA)

---

Alternatively, using the `binaryLogic` package (39 bytes):

```r
!sum(binaryLogic::as.binary(scan()))%%2
```

Comment: I don't know R too well, but I'm pretty sure `==0` can be `<1` :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You're right. Should have seen that. Thanks!

Comment: [43 bytes?](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0JTsbg0VyOxWC@vNDe1KDNZIzOvJCTfKbOkGCinqamqavQ/TcNYkytNw9AQRJqbm4MoE7CQqanmfwA)

Comment: @ngm That works! Didn't think it would be that simple. Thanks. I'm getting 44 bytes though.

Comment: Nice! [34 bytes is possible](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0JTsbg0VyMzryQk3ymzpBgoYGegqapq9D9Nw1iTK03D0BBEmpubgygTsJCpqeZ/AA)

Comment: @Giuseppe Wow! I've definitely learned some R code golf tips from this one. Thanks.

Comment: This works as well I think : [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0JTsbg0V6NCVV/VKE7DwMrYUFNTVdXof5qGsSZXmoahIYg0NzcHUSZgIVNTzf8A "R – Try It Online")
But requires a bit of an explanations :)

Comment: @digEmAll This is a good suggestion for Giuseppe's answer!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that answer... I'll post there

Comment: [it's easy to turn this into a full program](https://tio.run/##K/r/X7G4NFcjM68kJN8ps6RYozg5MU9DU9POQFNV1ei/qel/AA) for some more bytes

Comment: @JayCe Easy enough! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
<?=1&~substr_count(decbin($argn),1);
```

To run it:

```
echo '<input>' | php -nF <filename>
```

Or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7WUK2uuDSpuKQoPjm/NK9EIyU1OSkzT0MlsSg9T1PHUNP6/3/jf/kFJZn5ecX/dfPcAA)

Prints `1` for true, and `0` for false.

-1 byte thanks to [Benoit Esnard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38454/benoit-esnard)!

Comment: I think you can save one byte by removing the modulo operation: `<?=1&~substr_count(decbin($argn),1);`. This one also prints 0 for false.

Comment: Thanks @BenoitEsnard! That's very clever, I've updated my answer :) You learn something new every day!

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
ḃo-0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO5nxdg///TQ3/AwA)

[With multiple test cases](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5U@zJ/RofRwV@ejjhVA9sQ9IHbtw60T/j/c0Zyva/D/f7SBjoKhjoKRjoKxjoKJjoKpjoKZjoK5joKFjoIlUBAoYQpSYmAY@x8A) ( is evil and  is not.)

Uses something I discovered  recently about the `-` predicate: its documentation just says "the difference of elements of [input]", but what it actually does is "sum of even-indexed elements (starting from 0th) of input, minus the sum of odd-indexed elements of input".

Here,

`ḃ` converts the number into an array of binary digits,

`o` sorts them to bring all the 1s together.

Now, if there were an even number of 1s, there would be an equal number of 1s in even indices and odd indices. So the `-` after that would give a 0. But if there were an odd number of 1s, there would be an extra 1 sticking out, resulting in the difference being either -1 or 1.

So, finally, we assert that the difference is `0`, and get a true or false result according to that. With [more flexible output requirements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12308/8774), this could be removed for a 3 byte answer, with 0 as truthy output and -1 and 1 as both falsey outputs.

Answer (score 6):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), <s>90</s> <s>65</s> 63 bytes

```
DOWRITEIN:1
DO:2<-'#0$#65535'~?':1~:1'
DOREADOUT:2
PLEASEGIVEUP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz57@/n@t/FPzzIM8TV08/KkMvF38rIRldd2UBF2czU1NhUvc5e3cqwzspQHSgV5Oro4h8aYmXEFeDj6hjs6u4Z5hoa8P9/sGuYq58ChAQA)

Ungolfed and expanded (for what it's worth) with C style comments.

```
DO WRITE IN :1 //Store user input in 1
DO :2<-:1~:1 //Select just the ones. So will convert binary 10101 to 111
DO :3<-:?2 //Run the unary xor over the result. Essentially, xor with the right bitshifted
           //(with wraparound) value).
DO :9<-#0$#65535 //Intermingle the 16 bit values of all 0's and all 1's, to create a
                 //32 bit number with 1's in the odd positions.
DO :4<-:9~:3 //It turns out that at this point, evil numbers will have no bits in odd
             //positions, and non-evil numbers will have precisely one bit in an odd
             //position. Therefore, the ~ will return 0 or 1 as appropriate.
PLEASE READ OUT :4 //Politely output
PLEASE GIVE UP //Polite and self explanatory
```

I had to make a few concessions to make this feasible in INTERCAL. The first is, as with all INTERCAL programs, numerical input must be written out. So if you want to input `707` you would provide `SEVEN OH SEVEN`.

The second is that INTERCAL doesn't really have proper truthy or falsy value. Instead, it will output the Roman Numeral `I` (1) if the number is not evil, or a 0 (typically represented as `-` since Roman Numerals can't normally represent 0).

If you want to flip those so that evil numbers return 1 and non-evil numbers return 0, you can change lines 4 and 5 from the ungolfed version as follows, although it does add 3 bytes.

```
DO:9<-#65535$#0
DO:4<-#1~:9~3
```

Answer (score 6):

## [evil](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil), <s>48</s> <s>42</s> <s>40</s> <s>39</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

<sup>golf 1: flipping many `m`s to `j`s and `j`s to `m`s saved quite a bit of marking mode changes</sup>
<sup>golf 2: do..while -> repeat..until</sup> 
<sup>golf 3: `tbxb` -> `sxb` - can be seen to be the same, but less intuitive</sup> 
<sup>golf 4: the `vzv` in `vtfvzv` turned out to be renundant, because the accumulator already zero at that point</sup>
<sup>golf 5: `aayuoy` -> `aluoy` and `tbuw` -> `tbaw`, now outputs 0x02 for evil and 0x00 for normal</sup>
I can confirm that this language is absolutely *evil*. Even though it is more powerful than e.g. brainfuck, it feels worse.
Inputs via char code, outputs via char code (0x02 = evil, 0x00 = normal). This would be slightly (probably by 1 byte) shorter if the output values could be merely consistent and not necessarily falsy and truthy.

Uses a trick: to count set bits, the code adds elements to the wheel, a circular list, and then calculates the list size's parity by setting the first one to 1, the second one to 2 and traversing the list 2 steps at a time until a non-zero element is found.

```
rvmvtfxjxutctbuvavsxbmaluoymiiptbaw
```

Here's an explained version (I do not expect anybody to understand the monstrosity above, but the explanation is in a spoiler so that you can try) (I was also writing the code immediately with these comments):

> ```
> COMMENTS ARE UPPERCASE, CODE IS LOWERCASE
>
> r READ INPUT AS CHAR CODE
> NOW DECREASE AND CHECK PARITY, WHILE ALSO COMPUTING N/2 IN THE FIRST PENTAL CELL
> v STORE TO FIRST PENTAL CELL
> m BEGINNING OF OUTER LOOP
>
> vtf IF ZERO, DONE
> NOW THE ACCUMULATOR HAS THE CORRECT VALUE AND THE PENTAL CELL IS ZERO, JUST LIKE IT SHOULD BE.
>
> x SET MARKING MODE INITIALLY
> j BEGINNING OF INNER LOOP
> x UNSET MARKING MODE AGAIN
> u FIRST DECREMENT
> IF ZERO (ODD), INCREASE BIT COUNTER AND PROCEED TO NEXT ITERATION
> tc THIS LANGUAGE SEEMS COMPARABLE TO MALBOLGE. THIS ADDS A NEW CELL TO THE WHEEL, A RESIZABLE CIRCULAR LIST. I USE IT AS THE BIT COUNTER
> tb GO TO NEXT ITERATION OF OUTER LOOP
> ODD CASE HANDLED. EVEN CASE IS (MUCH) SIMPLER
> u SECOND DECREMENT
> vav INCREMENT FIRST PENTAL CELL
>
> sxb IF ZERO, GO TO THE NEXT ITERATION OF THE OUTER LOOP; ELSE GO TO THE NEXT ITERATION OF THE INNER LOOP; EQUIVALENT TO TBXB.
>
> m END OF OUTER LOOP
>
> DO SORCERY TO COUNT WHEEL CELLS.
> al SET FIRST WHEEL CELL TO 1 (AND RESET THE ACCUMULATOR BACK TO 0 BY SWAPPING)
> uoy SET SECOND CELL TO -1
>
> NOW IN A LOOP CHECK WHETHER 1 OR 2 GOES FIRST AND OUTPUT THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER
>
> m BEGINNING OF THE LOOP
> ii GO RIGHT TWICE
> p READ WHEEL
> tb IF STILL ZERO, GO BACK
> NOW THE NON-ZERO ELEMENT WAS FOUND
> a INCREMENT SO THAT VALUES ARE ACTUALLY FALSY AND TRUTHY. IF THAT REQUIREMENT WASN'T THERE, THE CODE COULD BE REDUCED SLIGHTLY (AT LEAST BY REMOVING THIS BYTE)
> w PRINT
> ```

Now, the most ***evil*** part. This code does not work with the normal interpreter, because it has a bug. The bug is that the command to add a cell to the wheel quite literally doesn't add a cell to the wheel (to be specific, it's missing `wheelSize++;`). I assume that the bug is obvious enough for me to avoid accusations of adding new built-ins to the language.

You can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVhtbyI5Ev68/IqakW6m2YQGsrerVQhzIgmZoEsgImRHq4gPBgzppF9Yt5uXneO3z1W537tNEnSHRpnudvmpctVT5bKf2YrVnmcvP37Uf4bRk@UD/mMwt4Qva0vm@2BMmW2DJWHFhW95LjTMkyp4c2AuWK7kYik4/q3AzzD3BMgnDnxl2bAU3kIwx3IXYDN3EbAFN@HWExz8JZ9ac4twtyivdNJ0mjphPk/kj2FtyScvkGrIl8ydMTED25oIJrYmzqFpoydOoChnz2DCYcYls2w@wwd/KqylRKN9MrhoGtlGALE64LbP14RmwjX@PYYeGoCLfw58CT4jY5kkV6ivkr1wms5cHOAbiU6zOTBy34rZ1ixWY0IHpW1vzcVUrY5L9BeKCTVdWZSYMPUcB5fpm/CwXJYnlJxACORIjJProW3O0uYOx7DMMDihc6O4VU3oe5KHa5DKZzjoeoTgB9MnEsZYKfv9rSvZBrgQGFHEIRtjdz/4aOcpPdHvGfkTLsHZ3nuBmPIr9ILJV3YkXtvze6bByLRT4lSTPghuc1ryjEl@Cs1G/Zdm/aTROKGxToBcEKcw8hz4JrjrT59eUxDpH0aI15YvPbGNDEd9DYI/@VXBw4h/A7gi0sMymNjWNGF7ZNHMTCY2M3aFEyfBAoO/iWVRsl7BSHhCKv@Ylmf2Bt3NlCsutopj5LGeuwzkvRScOa1KZWpT5im3JhH1YRi4Lpsgx75DvX73cH7Tu4Bh93bwR/cSRgO47fy7C6PrLlwMbu96N90h3I8Gd@rtptPr9/pfoXM@eBjBFQ5Cv3Pbva9UKIaTreSPY0Dmc/sYfBXFY1iiTma3lATmeTh85/mxhHoMhfCxIHdv/c1jwfA5lKRnFCWN0AnnTDwPveYmzL5l4gXaIEWAkkoCRyRGJA6Mh6nlMMs10F3IWLSciYVfhe9KmH71ejh0HsznXGB45gjo8jVkPxvVVmaCNQeDYEybuwv5BGfQrGI8ZSDcrJgU25we@lsIHzLBhXZBhn5kQEFWqXxsjHOmxI6cFD/OvJJu5UBcHOo0EXBmlJAUGi5uAl@gUdUMKohgbjKsN@7MMKZPTFQnJZwdBpbqWwSUHd5hBZJYQIwMyYHnA7LLPGe0ffyISD/V64rqPIoSvRgkJL0wYEY1p6/7R@8GRsj2e@j174jQw8EtdEJe3991L3pXPUyJXl9lQ2f49eG22x/dm1jOL647/a@ULjigOFSFq4f@xag36FMKYSoNh71LSqPOyExUlq37KFbOSs43z5tATuUkWLGVv5k4zA68rWPhnjNh648Zo7Eibvg0kDwO0C6kdsRphRmuFZYLJ@u6NG9Q/68pouA@l9lwh8mGQghgLrg8xxzzywIRUvgSsV1nkkqzxOiMQSXFES@SqgBf2tCAT5/SOoHZlCpPORhyeuDyaO5jMmGceqlkkwjcnD2vOjYqbeiOb1SWchMpK1SxinO@3U6LV97KsBCEo@nCI3DJnSW0i4PqNaKMEkygx6kQNUwG5brVbrTAOktk8OXoKG@DGnu0xlQbUSM@Zcmg7KPvr3vhTrGpEE81N1vuy7Npbkc3rZMPVBihkCEZ4Q4a3Sj4hnhR/pr1WLPRGBeGI/Y2W4X8yE5LM2ZcJL9eZ@lrsquln3MLDEmr/DJ1ZtmFqm9OuIMpgSp8dj7nKQPMlgWR56II1v6fUtuxC6byGpbmWGWOHKpP/Mw@n@a@KtcfHbVKHye4V7y0dBATDcRz4CyNOcPmuHoI1FQDtfbQt8ZBMDMNTCZv4gi2MtlTa7ZK6VNMo3b0cNQcl61JkWrlwaRuKDKeIUWyDNDC5ClbEikRsGxwLDfWC@4OcCjXsYQKGGcrbnQOCs58H12ofTsIabHHqjAXH5OUHB8C@qQBzSa3kb4cUcP3j3yb@m49lo7qaWSN5DnSktb5A5Q8a5Tsl37Zu/SML9G2ziEm2DoT4r0v5eiehMqRWKOXwj05xBznII@47ydDDcOkT/xE5gyzPjs7JU6tecgavPdSh2yCV6pR2GehVZnZaQGqwUFWLffViLcCvR/yLw2kv2bLw3YDscew4uHnbSRfg0TO7FAfiG5MOobDNlC5F/bD/wIb6Nat2532Q6x02dJ@R319Z9k4OH3XOuoLSx66CW10zMrfJnzIvh@Cvd2Xnm8Vs/2Qf@@hcGZb35X71pguu0wfqnba@P4Ee6I1LvCNbtTIOuJfVEFxX8l4m6iqQdKe87KnOm3rkpwBMyc7SgMyqdydaTMj9QRdzr5lEZ08/5@WZBNsV3J/1MxmjErqLS4B6nW6ZRj0b/6Ey97VVXfY7V904VtvdA3JQK8/6g7vhl38Cz24Gjz0Lyv6PvNLVHyjw2oxOK@eRbWnKxKNT77YluTOWoeeTd86n@4q@zr3CPBL0saDVavtPfhGj7Vm8Vyo64/jI1t0fYhK6ZKTmtxbRk76/s9jaOK/347h5Bh@w7ff8e0E//xysmulV6NRY6weN7kLBFyGw/yXfHdPX5nrr7nI53TRn7@HfizEkYJubD4RbPVDu1F2cwIdPvwnzOt4WTmv0y@yj/47O2vqIhId5EOcELRcacKNulBa3rz7CPNIc0WVXlTEHpMxSnKXXGiEkpzUn@ll@llmGx/9/UFat/Zcj8mcC1Toww6jWF11kc5fEueCFlXh@62PLjA1l7ZpXN66Uy1FcF/swi01vFbIAkRGeIE0lwJjULj63VV2lR8/pmD0B6Puae6@9fxPukgdwsXgsvuh@l8) using my fixed interpreter.

Comment: Bonus: Is you code as a base64 number evil?

Comment: @petStorm seems to be evil both in base64 and base36 :)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 36 bytes

```c
c;f(n){for(c=0;n;c++)n&=n-1;n=~c&1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc/BCsIwDMbxu08RCo6GOTCsZWCZvoiXEVYZaCbdPI356tWbVJB6zOHH/wtXF@YY2XktuPgxaG73ThyXJUrRSkVO2icX5NZ46wbRuGzuYZDZawVQQ3WE7XQWtQOvawSAE6g5PHoFB1C@u069QvcRRIkgwoxomiYR7xszDZOuMnWuAdYmwtqsgC/xx@epoHyDTCrML7HGFw)

Method from K&R https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan

Must be compiled with optimization level 0

Comment: Doesn't compile on gcc 5.4.0: `error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token` (arrow is pointing at the `f` in the function name). What compiler flag(s) do I need?

Comment: Doesn't work with `-O`.

Comment: "Returns 0 for truthy, 1 for falsey"  
Is this legal? Not trying to discredit your answer, just curious, and because it would save me a byte.  
Note: The word truthy in the question links to [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey#2194). And [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/169724/is-this-number-evil#comment409983_169724) also mentions truthiness.

Comment: @nwellnhof @villapx Compiles fine on my 7.3.0 - just make sure you're not missing the `-O0` compiler flag.

Comment: @Borka223 hmmm after months of perusing this site, I was under the impression that truthy and falsey could be anything, so long as they are consistent within your solution. However, the answer you linked certainly seems to contradict that. I went ahead and added the byte. Thanks

Comment: I assume we are calling the function with only `n`? If so, `c` is uninitialised.

Comment: @gastropner Thanks. Interesting bug - it had 50/50 chance of working properly. If the uninitialized value was an even number (and not large enough to overflow), it would work fine

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

- Saved two bytes thanks to [Misha Lavrov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74672/misha-lavrov).

```
2∣DigitCount[#,2,1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73@hRx2KXzPTMEuf80rySaGUdIx3DWLX/AUWZeSUOwak5qckl0SGJSTmp0Vk61Vk6BjqGBgYGtbE6abH/AQ)

Comment: `2∣` is an improvement on `EvenQ`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73@hRx2KXzPTMEuf80rySaGUdIx3DWLX/AUWZeSUOwak5qckl0SGJSTmp0Vk61Vk6BjqGBgYGtbE6abH/AQ)

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>32</s> <s>29</s> <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 21 bytes

```rb
->n{("%b"%n).sum%2<1}
```

Where we use the fact that `sum` sums each character and given `1` is an odd number, and because we eventually do modulus `2`, that makes it equivalent to `count(?1)`:

```rb
->n{("%b"%n).count(?1)%2<1}
```

Where `<1` is a shorter substitute for `even?`:

```rb
->n{n.to_s(2).count(?1).even?}
```

Where `n` parameter should be an integer.

Comment: `%2==0` saves 1 byte.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard, thank you, thank you! I couldn't accept that python solution would be shorter :) wow, now I see it got 27 :/

Comment: Instead of `%2==0` can't you do something like `%2<1` to save a byte?

Comment: @auhmaan Oh yeah, even better.

Comment: @auhmaan, my hero, now we are on par with python. I wonder though, wasn't there a rule to return boolean by `1` or `0` if desired? Or only for languages where these evaluate to `true/false` by convention?

Comment: The challenge specifically says that it wants a truthy or falsey value, which the  [current consensus on Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey?answertab=votes#tab-top) defines based on how a conditional handles it, so for non-evil numbers your Ruby code would have to output `false` or `nil`.  (Note that's language specific, so it's OK that my Python answer returns `0` or `1`.)  Sometimes challenges just ask for you to output one of two distinct values, though, in which case `1` and `0` would be fine.

Comment: @JackBrounstein, thank you very useful. I couldn't find a list of officially accepted rules for the site :/

Comment: `("%b"%n).count(?1)%2` is the same as `("%b"%n).sum%2`

Comment: @GB, wow, nice suggestion. I can't understand why such method went into the API but works for the task at hand.

Answer (score 5):

## x86-16, 3 bytes

NASM listing:

```
 1                                  parity16:
 2 00000000 30E0                        xor al,ah
 3 00000002 C3                          ret
```

16-bit integer function arg in AX (which is destroyed), return value in PF.

The hardware calculates the parity of the result for us, in [x86's Parity Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_flag).  The caller can use `jp` / `jnp` to branch, or whatever they like.

Works exactly like [@cschultz's Z80 / 8080 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/169724/is-this-number-evil/169733#169733); in fact 8086 was [designed to make mechanical source-porting from 8080 easy](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6500).

Note that PF is only set from the low byte of wider results, so `test edi,edi` wouldn't work for an x86-64 version.  You'd have to horizontal-xor down to 16 bits, or `popcnt eax, edi` / `and al,1` (where 0 is truthy).

Answer (score 5):

## x86-16 machine code, 3 bytes

```
32 C4     XOR  AL, AH     ; PF = (AX >> 8) XOR AL
C3        RET             ; return to caller
```

Input is `AX`, output is in `PF`; `PE` if `True` (Evil) or `PO` if `False` (Not Evil).

This is actually the exact use of the [x86 Parity Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_flag), with the only twist being that normally it only operates on the LSB of a WORD register.  However, you can get the Parity of a WORD by `XOR`'ing the high byte and the low byte.

Example output from a test program for PC DOS:

[image]

DANG IT, I should have looked at the other answers first...  @PeterCordes submitted this in 2018...

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169903/84624

Answer (score 4):

Since the [previous J solution by Adam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169775/78410) is invalid for numbers having odd number of binary digits, here is a corrected one:

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
1-~:/&#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/w1166z01ZSt/mtypSZn5CukKRjDGKYwhqEhjGVubg5jmiDUmf4HAA)

Anonymous tacit verb.

#### How it works

```
1-~:/&#:    Right argument: the number to test.
      #:    Convert to binary digits
  ~:/&      Reduce by not-equal (same as XOR for zero-one values)
1-          Invert the result
```

Alternatively, J has a built-in `XOR` that computes bitwise XOR over the input.

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
1-XOR&#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/w11I/yD1JSt/mtypSZn5CukKRjDGKYwhqEhjGVubg5jmiDUmf4HAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 20 bytes

```julia
n->count_ones(n)%2<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcc7CoAwEAXA3lO8RthALOIvjXoVETWwEjYS4/lXp5vrjbyNGjBDpVn29EpZk5wPianbyWlIGQwWUGfhnIX33qL/MwymAu7MUqJQIDamOuVQ/QA)

Answer (score 4):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (-O0),  <s>36</s>  31 bytes

```cpp
int f(int i){i=!i||i%2-f(i/2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxLDoMgGIT3nmKaponEmFKXgt7FIDR/omAQulHPbpEuOotZfPNQy1K/lTrvZNUURw1Jbg1eD3Nf/NlHq@B8f5INMOXlxDbqbrTv9GjqhJ4NE0fO54FsybAVSDLO/@odFyD54hwCVUUpB5kyDRnDGsa2VS4GSAm6LBNtx0ngyD9eh@gtuCiO8ws)

---

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 35 bytes

```cpp
int f(int i){return!i||i%2-f(i/2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY07DoMwEER7TjFRFAkLoTiU2OEuyJ9oJbCRMWmAsxNjimwxxZvPqmmq1dC7z3Enp4ZFG0jycwymH7viz75GRR@6g1yELU8ltgYTl@ButG30aOqEnw0Te86MPbmSYS2QzvpwVd5cgOSLcwhUFSUfZMtUZAxz1G2r/BIhJeiUTIzTg8Ced65/4KLYjx8)

---

Here is my first attempt at code golfing, hope I didn't break any rule I might have missed.

Edit:
- Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Jonathan Frech : replaced `!=` by `-` and `return` by `i=` (the last replacement does not seem to work with clang though)
- Since there seems to be a debate whether I should use gcc -O0 abuse, I thought I could just give both versions

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You may be able to save a byte by golfing `!=` to `-` and another four by golfing `return` to `i=`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech It's been a long time since I did C++, does it implicitly return the last assigned expression in a function if there's no return statement? I'm guessing it's a gcc thing?

Comment: It is a gcc specific undefined behaviour abuse on optimization level O0.

Comment: By switching to K&R C, you can get it down to 23 bytes (very impressive!) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BU4MwEIXv@RVrHGwiYCle1DT6Q7QHGsC@GUycJO2F8tsxyMHxuN@@9/atKT@NmW9hzXBuO9qH2MI9nF7ZPzTgmNjcC8gR@gbXK7K6TOO2lmqajbMhkjk1nu4R3VHARro0g6SREYXYRJh1Hd6fD3qsJpV47/yvEPpJoSxVMmx1LZMGB72pNrlI5G4nF63v4tlbCopNjC2mrwZWrPl/OZXC/rFWyHNJ3z6xXvCsJZEFSZqy0F0wfFheoFhbymL56I3zF25dJJ5OTfMP "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @JonathanFrech: why do people insist on using that stupid `gcc -O0` hack?  It's not like the length of a language's total boilerplate matters much when comparing implementations.  Also, it makes it more interesting to choose between `return` vs. call-by-reference (updating `*i` in place).  I'd rather write C or C++ answers, not un-optimized-gcc-only answers, because un-optimized-gcc isn't a very useful language.

Comment: @PeterCordes For one I do not insist on this compiler-specific quirk, but I merely suggested it as it does save bytes. Our current policy allows every such quirk in any language implementation; I do not think that is "stupid". Furthermore, we strive to golf our submissions as far as possible. If you do not like this method, you can always write in a more specific flavour of C, like _C clang_ or _C using O1_.

Comment: @JonathanFrech: When I golf in C, I like to golf in ISO C89 and write portable code that works with `gcc -O0` or `clang -O3`.  If there's something interesting to be gained by assuming 2's complement or something, then I'll mention it.  I know calling it "stupid" is going a bit far, but I *really* dislike it.  Partly because I like looking at compiler asm output, and `-O0` is dumb.  I don't think this was the intent of the "works on at least one implementation".  An output arg like [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167273) can work in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>37</s> 33 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Neil's idea of subtracting the least-significant two bits instead of the most-significant two bits*

```
^(((?=(((x*)(?=\5$))*))\3x){2})*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/LbsIwEEV/hUYIZkITHi0scA2rLtiwKMvSShYMzrTGsWwDKY9vT8OiUjdXVzpXujpf6qjCxrOLWXC8Jb8v7Tf91F5aOrXeSL9WDuAsZ/20/gSAuWyiSrEp63EbMUVcP1V4Gd0wbddp/4x5LFfRs9WAeTC8IZg8Zs@IIsiBOBVsCMBIT2pr2BIgPkh7MAYvWpo8OMMRulkXBe8ArNS5IatjgbPR9cphqZbA0ikfaGEj6PfBB@IfoP/Azobz4fSOMRa@PCULe1SGty2vrKZpK@kZsSs9CH6RJLjXw@YwqZLckyMVgTHfq7gpwCNeQqfjGqUId4uhcIcYom8m4narB9loPPkF)

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number.

```
^
(
    # Subtract the two least-significant "1" bits as
    # they would be in tail's binary representation.
    (
        # Divide tail evenly by 2 as many times as we can, atomically
        (?=
            (((x*)(?=\5$))*)
        )\3
        x                # Subtract a 1 bit
    ){2}
)*                       # Loop as many times as possible...
$                        # and only match if the final result is 0.
```

### Regex (Perl / Java / PCRE / Python / Ruby), 26 bytes

```
^((((x*)(?=\4$))*+x){2})*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7LasMwEPyVJYhY6wd@0PRQWYkDybWn3pJUpCUGgZq4kgsuQv11Z@MEuodlZ3Z2Z7qTNYvx6xeYFeDN5fNogOWCoKw367f1MkB7sZw5WYh6KdCDbgmh76w@9zDbn2ciQGOk64zueZRFqfv5cD2dqDQr0xJP3zfR6p8tiMcXplDcfjlyPNrG1BX6xuzKg6ReHMTDVz8g07Wc1jQlCXrdAufREMEAJEIE@Qc5szl65ubzKdyUjYKX4p6VaRFCUGr7ulFqfOdUQ4x8JfdPDDFOBvRVwJiNY5FVi@cr) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb9swDHzvr@CMDpGcVE2KbQ9TjWIbNqDAug3tY5oBii0namXak@TGbZDfnlGO91GgepFIno66E@/Ugzq5K@73pmpqF@COYmFqkUr4P9MGY1/MOb3SHVWOmnZpTQ65Vd7DlTIIWxhyPqhA20NtCqiowm6CM7gC5VZ@vuAQ1q7eePjc5boJpqabRwBfjNVQZqg3/ZElIq8LLaiecPmxLUvtdHGtVaEdLHvY8yT7c3MIS87l0NdPgtysIz9jPluSBlV8NagZ568ybK3lpmRe6F@tsp4lp2maJpxvn0MPDIyFFwm2xBD@MhDBKTEsCXcv/Tgb3eIo7kHuDrndDxWCdgguG06ktmpiA88lubGsa6sVwlNWEqOWcJMrRJJusGkDZBDVDjl28@iDroRBLmHQ2cPEWvlvugv0zN5igMEQS28njgMICTFIHOrzBVgqR5TwjTWBJSf0CYQPgFOqXGKgMXCiUc5rCpidTxd8Ajh7sSisxlVYn5/BBUQkvKdttiDGfK3cfNENevoIZwsJH5xTj16UxlrWTUbdqDcFoKxd1EbPyHAqAc8znNE2HpPAKxXyNTlUEZsT1SFi/eQiDfgnIj9MjNg41bChRV43j9/La4UrTZ2mE@Q8Ki2BVdQeC/Iu/u0TH0yuybGNM0Gz@KlcPmXBtfF//pUb8jCULHntE7KEy11cR3Gq9j8ZrS7l7CK7fXPMeTru@PZsx9PjfZyZ/fTk7O273w) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDfa8IwEH73rwgh0FxNtRZ1SCy@bIPB2MO2N@tC7VJbVtOQRiiIf3t3lT0tcMf9@r7vcrayw3ZnK0uYIymhc0pmxDp9Uk7bJi80D@azcKdUlTdeFe3Z1o12Gc9AZu/zLhAkQCuxqE56HDBeG99xpZ5fXp@UAkEWgJRILCe1qVWnPae2cHp2zIsf79Cppj7XngpCl8lmuVk/JJsVBTkpW8dZncaSNWmJ7B3/@Hx8eQMJV1KXnDX7zrtGG4wgWhzSlGaGAg53lyN2sCxiES1gxOveNu235jSiAscl4ov2YvyI3SYI2iMB@vggJ4Tclc1fzsw2vfcxmk4BpQm/X@ic@6LizAkUG8@lc8@DPhDMAAC5jivWoIuqHfeSBL@ykGTMCTPyhjK3f2flIIcvjq8Pge/SbMkAwmkP1@QGIRuGOEpW618) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BboMwEEX3nGJkZeEhgDBNs4BaOQilUtQ6iStnjMauQhTl7BRTdVZf8/S@/niPF08vs72OniOEeyjYnM1UfAdPHbBmIcT8IZebcpQH/b7bIObbCR/NE/PNvOBetaUaOrC6zk6ewYGl1FSF@GWpzcBpV4XR2ShFKTADewJnSDp8a1pwvRq06@shgyRTkvlIZyMtRZkAFn9JDbhVuPSlgnVlFcyRPy@SCxCTyGmFidoWRk4Wrg@tuv9B/idWN7bRyBBZEuJcl83r/hc) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Ra8IwEMff9yluRTDX2dAWtwdjkKJl7MWB8626sGGsgRBLGrFjbF@9S9zmwR3c//6/u7On94/eAoeVrGXXUCPPsCjWBbXybTf6FSeTp8fl86qcFy8lA8VTBueD0hI0r6VrbwDUHnSVZFvOo42JmB/oKqU0ybcMpNl5h1do22jlyDAZ4h9CtTS1OxCc5p6pPO@xK7I/WjCgDASRuqNQJEuR0mC8tt532UWiLooNAv8Gy4KgbsOfzcm1l33h78z3VhkH5v9EqCGFKJcLIfpX4qOLkcz4ZjxAjO86/My/MB70fZrk9w8/) - Ruby

```
^
(
    # Subtract the two least-significant "1" bits as
    # they would be in tail's binary representation.
    (
        # Divide tail evenly by 2 as many times as we can, atomically
        ((x*)(?=\4$))*+
        x                # Subtract a 1 bit
    ){2}
)*                       # Loop as many times as possible...
$                        # and only match if the final result is 0.
```

### Regex (.NET), 29 bytes

```
^(((?>((x*)(?=\4$))*)x){2})*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBBT@MwFITv/ApTIdWvTaK0WjhgXJAiDkgg0BaJwy5IJn0US64T@TnFNPS3FzcBLvhmzdjzzZSUlpXDnVUrpFqVyObv5HHVNqTtkhWyqCxVBkV/v8fgs7@4bIxyl6F2SKSjQZRGEbFVS155XbJ1pRfsRmnLOLRr5RjJi8HuiXN@PuM8jICfy/9/jgBGEKCdbmF0tBuIvdFJi28sJmDglM2bZ/IuBvNJQtk12qV/TaeQdPpt7ffZWVGtam1wAaL3MiNeKse19czKXHAji4isFtfaIgc4lLYxRlg5gVa/cDvLocgenPbYGzqMWppsXhvt@TAdgtj/pRMUB/FB/cUxm358HEYhu3fvd8oR8vpf/phUTbTCb@n7WTrpPQjfsXxwZdfKxMWcsks8ZW2@HSQGBBrCbr3QjTLvlxiGYaLhp@ImVtRnEoUej5MwllGGSOmyK7pRvnzlAbqem189N3IifhC6zPDFCGLbnV2eTo9PPgE)

Comment: `^((((.*)(?=\4$))*.(.*)(?=\5$)){2})*$` is only 36 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 6 bytes

```
1=/~2\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#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)

- `~2\` convert input to base-2 representation, and `not` it (flip `0`s and `1`s)
- `1=/` do an equals-reduce seeded with `1`; returns `1` if there are an odd number of 1's in the inverted base-2 representation and `0` if there are an even number(or none at all)

Comment: Seems to be a false positive on 7 (`111`, `(1=1)=1`).

Comment: Good catch - revised the logic and verified that it now covers at least the first 50-ish terms from https://oeis.org/A001969

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 29 bytes

```python
lambda n:~bin(n).count('1')&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PycxNyklUSHPqi4pM08jT1MvOb80r0RD3VBdU83wf5otXnkurrT8IoWS1OIShcw8BQ1jHQVDQx0Fc3NzHQUTIMfUVNOKi7OgKDOvRCFNA6RM8z8A)

Returns 1 if True, else 0.

Converts the number to a binary string like '0b11', counts the number of 1s, gets the complement of result, and returns the last bit of the complement (thanks, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53560/cdlane!) (1 if the original number was even, 0 if it was odd).

Comment: No fewer bytes but `lambda n:~bin(n).count('1')&1` replaces the modular division with something potentially less expensive.

Comment: You can do `lambda x:~x.bit_count()%2` which is shorter

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
*.base(2).comb(~1)%%2
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##Rc7NCoJAEMDx@zzFEBm7ZYKVCi5GHerUMbr7MYG0qbgqRdSLdevFrK3Q2/Kf3wxbUCndtlaEjWvFAuB8xVGcJ4RBO7aiUBGbcSvOzxF72NwwZq3QZFWRqjBAmWakXk9rc1jvBOgz@89AQCHDDCdfJeCYl/@F6RIZ@ie6smGaFXXFTfSbUNbEhnQpKK4o4cjxBoipQv2NHnbCxMEvYrDs6wDu7VyXfVkT2LZ@bkOpCDzP6/qiJ47TkTc)

### Expanded:

```perl6
*\        # WhateverCode lambda (this is the parameter)
.base(2)  # Str representing the binary
.comb(~1) # find the "1"s

%% 2      # is the count of "1"s divisible by 2?
```

Comment: `{:3(.base(2))%%2}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
Even@Sum@Bin
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5BC4IwFAfwu5/ioRkaCzITQTBWUVCHCIwuYwexWQOdw82@/prSreN7/P/v/Uqty@rNTJ3l5vhhAhdDi/dcmCtjT0VmUlYv6tx6LvSdKX0oFVOkRkBiBFGEIE1TBBs7JAn95Yi7dGEB6xV1nLrVkOVw6vq21PPMDXwVgq9cjINLx8X4yXt4dehwIYcpegW8hUI2XJNd05zHNbGX/witRjCVqImtxBosYeR8AQ)

(Old 13 bytes: `` Even@1&`~@Bin ``)

This is a composition of three functions:

1. `Bin`
2. `Sum`
3. `Even`

This checks that the `Sum` of the `Bin`ary expansion of the input is `Even`.

Comment: :| i have no words

Comment: @ASCII-only quite succinct, eh? c:

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <strike>18</strike> 16 bytes

```
[2~rd1<M+]dsMx2%
```

Returns (to the stack) 0 for evil and 1 for not evil

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2L8P9qorijF0MZXOzal2LfCSPV/wX8A)

Fairly straightforward - recursively applies the combined quotient/remainder operator `~` to the new quotient and adds all the remainders together, then mods by 2 <strike>(after spending two bytes to flip to a standard truthy/falsy)</strike>.

Edited to reflect consensus that 0 for truthy and 1 for falsy is okay, especially in a language that has no sort of `if(boolean)` construct.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit function. Can take any array of integers as argument.

```apl
≠⌿1⍪2∘⊥⍣¯1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hngkc9@w0f9a4yetQx41HX0ke9iw@tN/yf9qhtwqPevkd9Uz39H3U1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIP/pykYKxgaKphYGCiYGCuYmgIA)

`2∘⊥⍣¯1` convert to binary, using as many digits as needed by the largest number, separate digits along primary axis

`1⍪` prepend ones along the primary axis

`≠⌿` XOR reduction along the primary axis

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 20 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to Roberto Graham

```java
n->n.bitCount(n)%2<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZA9C8JADIb3/oogCHeoB/WDDn4sguDg5CgO11ol9UyLlxOk9LfXaxUUujglPHnz5iPTDz3KTtc6Mdpa2GmkMgAoXGwwAcuafXjkeIKbL4k935EuhyPo@8VKKAOvBci8iXKMRp0dJYw5qS3x5pODh7CsabQiFSOvc0csSPbHi7BuuudvE04ti8mwUcv5l4RhB0VR1GHTbuds9kVVM@P3mlaBxIDDP9aXZWu7f1pObyp3rAr/BzYkcNCD5Qp6A69SuijMU6D8jKzqFw)

Comment: 20 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZBNa8JAEIbv/opBKOxiXEit5KDmoFDooSeP0sMa1zDpOhuys4IEf3vcqGAhp55meOeZdz4qfdbT6vDbFVZ7D98aqR0B1GFvsQDPmmM4OzzAKZbElhukcvcDuim9hHYUWYAqmqjAaNUxUMHoSH0@k@UXsSlNk8DaOWs05RAZWHU0zUntkTcuEAuSb@/LtOvNFg9PNp7FLOlpuXgpaTqQsiwbaB/Dzvn8JV37GX@PuxNIDJj8/xrZ3qdsL57NSbnAqo5fYksCJ2NY5TCeRErpurYXgfK5wbW7AQ "Java (JDK 10) – Try It Online")

Comment: @RobertoGraham Thanks, forgot you can call static methods on a variable.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 14 bytes

```
ThueMorse@#<1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/T8kozTVN7@oONVB2cZQ7b@@g0K1sY6CoaGOgrm5uY6CCZBjaqqjYGZoBiTMzGpj/wMA)

The Nth element of the Thue-Morse sequence is 1 if the number of binary digits in N is odd, and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 34 bytes

```cs
bool f(int i)=>i<1||i%2<1==f(i/2);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BS8NAEIXP2V8xBIVdqJWkLQHT9NKToCh48GA9rOtGB@KsdCaCpPntcW1aETpzeMN7Mx/j@MKFrR9aRnqDh28W/1Eq11hmuIdOsVhBB18BX@HWImkD3fASQgO1RhJAU61wme12eJ4vs6qK7mVuykEl6ppklj89g3iWtWXPUEUgxJpN9pJloxZFMQ7zQ7BYTFRfqiRRdfzNuncNe9gfCpD@Yc0Buw7EofHTxy2K13CWxqvPVq6gO@72G7prZfRqfXRNn4IpTxE3SF6nG0pj2P/28AM)

There were already a few C# solutions, but this is the first recursive one.

In the case case when no more `1`'s are present, the function is terminated with a positive result. Otherwise the lowest bit is tested. If it is set, then the count of the rest of the bits must be odd. If it is unset, then the count of the rest of the bits must be even. We are able to determine whether the count of the remaining bits is even/odd by making a recursive call to half the input.

Answer (score 3):

## [SML](http://sml-family.org), 32 Bytes

```
fun%0=1| %n=(n+ %(n div 2))mod 2
```

**Explaination:**

- `%` is function name
- takes in input in repl and returns 1 if evil, 0 otherwise
- `n` is input, returns (n + %(n//2)) % 2

Made by 2 bored Carnegie Mellon Students

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and good first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, 24 bytes

```rust
|x:u8|x.count_ones()&1<1
```

Note that this only works for 8-bit numbers.
The following works for 64-bit (but is an extra character):

```rust
|x:u64|x.count_ones()&1<1
```

Testing code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let f = |x:u64|x.count_ones()&1<1;

    const TESTS: [(u64, bool); 6] = [
        (3, true),
        (11, false),
        (777, true),
        (43, true),
        (55, false),
        (666, false)
    ];

    for (x, b) in TESTS {
        assert_eq!(f(x), b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
b1O₂
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJiMU/igoIiLCIiLCI3NzciXQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```java
n->n.toString(n,2).chars().sum()%2<1
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@Okx* for something I shouldn't have forgotten myself..

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZY9LC8IwEITv/opFEBK0gfqg4OvuQS8e1cMao0bbjTRbQcTfXtPag@JlYZid/WYveMfocriWOkXvYYmWni0AS2zyI2oDq0oC7J1LDRJosQjWyeRAchKcVysMz8hWwwoIZlBSNCfFbs25pZOgXl8qfcbcC6l8kQnZ6U/jclLlbsU@Dbkmfnf2AFkoID7RzQ5QfuhsPItBDWxEHH@rJEm@5fBndTT6a1qjajM8CrahrB@eTaZcweoWCnBKwnbb4y23u6S0sLK58yrf)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                // Method with Integer parameter and boolean return-type
  n.toString(n,2)  //  Convert the integer to a binary String
   .chars()        //  Convert that to an IntStream of character-encodings
   .sum()          //  Sum everything together
    %2<1           //  And check if it's even
```

Note that the character encoding for `0` and `1` are `48` and `49`, but summing them and taking modulo-2 still holds the correct results because `48%2 = 0` and `49%2 = 1`.

Comment: `n.toString(n,2)` saves 4 bytes.

Comment: @Okx Not sure how I forgot about that one, lol.. Thanks! ;)

Comment: If you're allowed to use 1 and 0 instead of true and false (not sure for Java), you can change to: `~n.toString(n,2).chars().sum()%2` to save one byte.

Comment: @MarDev Unfortunately `0` and `1` aren't [truthy/falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210) in Java, only `booleans`/`Booleans` are. If a challenge would state two distinct outputs are allowed the `<1` could have been removed to save 2 bytes indeed. :)

Answer (score 2):

## x86 Assembly, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
F3 0F B8 44 24 04  popcnt      eax,dword ptr [esp+4] ; Load EAX with the number of ones in arg
F7 D0              not         eax ; One's complement negation of EAX
24 01              and         al,1 ; Isolate bottom bit of EAX
C3                 ret
```

-1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat's suggestion

Comment: @ceilingcat Good catch!

Comment: Suggest `inc eax` instead of `not eax`. Also may want to mention that this requires a processor with support for the `popcnt` instruction.

Comment: also you do not have to take arg from stack. see allowed calling conventions https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161497/17360 (Peter Cordes's more in-depth answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020/17360)

Comment: Note that you may return a boolean in FLAGS https://stackoverflow.com/a/48382679/3163618

Comment: Shouldn't 666 be a test case?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus  [666 is not evil](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z85P6@4RCE5I7FIIbM4tSwzJzrWVimmws04psLALabCySKmwsQkpsIIiA2A2MQAyjaMqXA2VrLmyswrUchNzMzT0Kzm4iooLSnWUNDQAApqaGlqaGpCjNTUMDMz07RXcg3z9FGyUvL3doxUUtC0xqPcEJvy2v///yWn5SSmF//XzTU2AgA "C (gcc) – Try It Online"); [616 is evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_the_Beast)

Comment: You can skip the inversion if you decide that `0` means truthy and `1` means falsy, or returning a result in EFLAGS could be easier to justify (either PF or ZF).  But yeah, the main saving would be a better calling convention.  e.g. make this an x86-64 answer and the arg will be in `edi` (x86-64 System V) or `ecx` (Windows x64).  Or simply use a 32-bit fastcall convention.

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 53 bytes

```forth
: f 1 swap begin 2 /mod -rot xor swap ?dup 0= until ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwFET3PcWj@0RjLQGLeha1pha0@XxT9PYxwc0bZoaZEDU9zBSq5Hwg4Hh/LsL1Ps0LOzavOGI0Jr5R/9V5XIXtkXVJ85OhrIQadVjFtmBOtOXJclOGpkMa5wq894X76vseyT8)

#### Explanation

Takes the xor-sum of the digits of the binary form of the number. (repeatedly divides by 2 and xors the remainder with the "sum" value)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f              \ begin a new word definition
  1 swap         \ place 1 on the stack below the input (n)
  begin          \ start an indefinite loop
    2 /mod       \ get the quotient and remainder of dividing n by 2
    -rot         \ move the sum and remainder to the top of the stack
    xor          \ xor the sum and remainder
    swap         \ move the quotient back to the top of the stack
    ?dup         \ duplicate if > 0
    0=           \ get "boolean" indicating if quotient is 0
  until          \ end the loop if it is, otherwise go back to the beginning
;                \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>43</s> <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 41 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Keeta

-2 bytes thanks to Sophia Lechner

+2 bytes thanks to sundar*

Original:

```
=MOD(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(A1),0,"")),2)=0
```

Shortest version:

```
=MOD(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(A1),0,)),2)=0
```

Comment: Since `""` is the default third argument for SUBSTITUTE, you can save two bytes with `=MOD(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(A1),0,)),2)=0`

Comment: If you change your "truthy/falsey" to be 1 and 0 instead of TRUE and FALSE, you can omit the last "=0"

Comment: (regarding clarifying last comment) - true would be 0 and false would be 1.  Then... you could further golf by omitting the 0 in the SUBSTITUTE statement and Excel assumes a 0 - but then you have to leave the quotes in.  Better to take out the quotes instead

Comment: @SophiaLechner, what version of Excel are you using? This doesn't seem to be the case in Excel 2013

Comment: @SophiaLechner Never mind, I see what you meant :)

Comment: Note that question links to a [meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey#2194) which gives a specific definition of truthy/falsey: you should be able to use the output in a conditional, for eg., `=IF()` in this case, and have it work like TRUE or FALSE. Many other questions have more flexible output requirements, so 0 for true and 1 for false would be fine there, but here I think you'll have to stick to the 41 byte version.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<1or n&1^f(n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz8Ywv0ghT80wLk0jT99I838aiKuQmadgrKNgaKijYG5urqNgAuSYmlpxcRYUZeaVaACVamr@BwA)

Returns a truthy value if exactly one of `the ones-bit is a 1` and `the result of calling this function on n/2 is truthy` is true (or `n==0`).  It works because `n/2` is equivalent to a right bitshift with floor division (so Python 2 only).

### Alternate version, also <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```python
g=lambda n:n<1or g(n&n-1)^1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P902JzE3KSVRIc8qz8Ywv0ghXSNPLU/XUDPO8H8akJunkJmnYKyjYGioo2Bubq6jYALkmJpacXEWFGXmlWgAlWtq/gcA)

Based on the K&R method of counting set bits referenced by vazt.

Both of these could be two bytes shorter if the output allowed falsey to mean evil.

**Edit:** Thanks to Amphibological for saving a byte!

Comment: You can remove the spaces between the `1` and the `or` to save +1 byte. Nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 28 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`(1+)\1
$+0
0

11

^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLSztBw1BbM8aQS0XbgMuAi8vQkIsrTuX/f2MQy9zcnMvEmMvUFAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`(1+)\1
$+0
```

Partial binary conversion (leaves extra zeroes).

```
0
```

Delete all the zeros.

```
11
```

Modulo the ones by two.

```
^$
```

Test whether the result is zero.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 6

```
!xFjQ2
```

#### Explanation

```
   jQ2 # Convert input to base 2 list
 xF    # reduce on XOR
!      # logical negation
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

Anonymous tacit function. Can take any integer array as argument.

```
1-2|1#.#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WylZfrcZKTdnqf2pyRr5CmoKxgqGhgrm5uYKJsYKp6X8A)

`1-` one minus (i.e. logical negation of)

`2|` the mod-2 of

`1#.` the sum (lit. the base-1 evaluation) of

`#:` the binary representation

Comment: Nice one! the boring approach is 9 bytes: `2|1+1#.#:`

Comment: This only seems to work because 777 in the input makes every number be represented in 10 bits. Replace it with e.g. 480 and the output flips.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Boring trumps incorrect.

Comment: @FrownyFrog Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB / Octave, <strike>28</strike> <strike>27</strike> 25 bytes

Using the `de2bi` function from the comm. systems MATLAB toolbox, you can achieve 25 bytes

```
@(n)~mod(sum(de2bi(n)),2)
```

Here is the 27 byte version which works without toolboxes (so works in Octave):

```
@(n)~mod(sum(dec2bin(n)),2)
```

The `dec2bin` conversion outputs a character array, so counting the occurence of the character `'1'` mod 2 gives the opposite of an evil number, negating that with `~` gives the answer.

Edited to include Sundar's comments (made it a valid anonymous function and saved by leveraging ASCII values instead of comparing to `'1'`).

Comment: de2bi(n) can replace dec2bin(n)=='1' if toolboxes are allowed.

Comment: I think submissions have to be either full programs or functions, so you'll have to add a `@(n)` at the beginning to make this an anonymous function. You can save 2 bytes by replacing `=='1'` with `-48` though.

Comment: I believe `@(n)~mod(sum(dec2bin(n)),2)`  would also work, for total 27 bytes. (Works because '1' is ASCII 49, so the result of the sum will be even only if there are an even number of '1' characters in the `dec2bin` result.)

Comment: @sundar Thanks, included

Comment: `@(n)~mod(sum(de2bi(n)),2)` works with toolboxes.

Comment: @Ander Cheers, orhym had suggested this too but don't know why I didn't add it in.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 33

```bash
dc -e2o?p|tr -d 0|wc -c|dc -e?2%p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcqxCsIwFEDRvV9xKXYs2NaSQbQ/4lKTV9olLyQBl/x7FEEc7@E@17TXTSNZUrZrEg7PxDBgjOEyMc9XnDYhHj5vtF3idqfl9Psbsbv@k8KjOksvoy6h5EjvOJfXR2z5@jJ2oTr1Ut8)

Reads input from STDIN.  Outputs 1 for True and 0 for False.

- `dc` converts input to a binary string
- `tr` removes zeros
- `wc` counts remaining ones (and trailing newline, which corrects sense of logic
- `dc` calculates count mod 2 and outputs the answer

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>50</s> <s>48</s> 45 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Charlie

```cs
n=>{int i=0;for(;n>0;n/=2)i^=n%2;return i<1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5BS8NAEIXv@RVzERLQpmktMWw3l0JPCoKCB6mwbjdlYJ2FmU2hlPz2mNYK4il9x8f7eJ@VOxvY9dYbEXhOjgkMkWgiWmBntoH8AV4OEt3XZN2SXSLFW/gMwdfQgO5J18ehAtRT1QROFdVTRbmeZfih6Wam2MWWCXBZqK6HS1Ty92cfcAtPBimVyEi79w0Y3kl23vwYnXKxWAWS4N3kjTG6RySXNuk8y9SwyHN45daNIYrijAzE2ngZhZRleWKuOLmf/56MJRaLq7WKqqoe/ot1Sdd/Aw)

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##nY7BasJAFEX3@Yq3ERJqjYmVNIyTTcFVC4UKLqSL6TiRgekbeG9SEMm3p1EDdZl6l5d7OFfzo/ZkOu0UM7xHpwj6cFDBaiCj9h7dET6OHMz3bN2gXlkMU/jy3lVQg@xQVqe@ApJzUXuKBVZzganME3qQOMkFmdAQAk3yVSbaDoaI6Nb04@0e3pTFmANZPOw@QdGBk8vm@umc4ceLR/bOzLZkg3m1aOI6XiSJuGzSFDbUmDFMlg1Qz6yV41FQURRX6h@ip8WfaCyzXN5xLivL8vnM3YraqO1@AQ) using a `for` instead of a `while`. And welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Sorry, [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##lY5BS8NAEIXv@RVzERLQpmktMWw3l0JPCoKCB6mwbjdlYJ2FmU2hlPz2mNYK4il9x8f7eJ@VOxvY9dYbEXhOjgkMkWgiWmBntoH8AV4OEt3XZN2SXSLFW/gMwdfQgO5J18ehAtRT1QROFdVTRbmeZfih6Wam2MWWCXBZqK6HS1Ty92cfcAtPBimVyEi79w0Y3kl23vwYnXKxWAWS4N3kjTG6RySXNuk8y9SwyHN45daNIYrijAzE2ngZhZRleWKuOLmf/56MJRaLq7WKqqoe/ot1Sdd/Aw) using your XOR solution.

Comment: @Charlie: Edited, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 39 bytes

*-1 Bytes thnks to @OMᗺ =D*

```javascript
_=>eval('for(z=0;_;_>>=1)z+=_&1;z%2<1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcjBCoQgEADQe/9ROSyFUwse3PFXxEpjF2milg7@vJ3Dd3w/d7lzPr77v5vc5GO38eJzoGzJ@MtF0QY@RCKprbbGEEJ6kW1Qp3r4YAt55u3k6PvIqwhCAlTPQSxKKVXcewTINw)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 65 bytes

So I'm terrible at codegolf, but here's my hacky string + LINQ solution:

```
n=>{return Convert.ToString(n,2).Where(c=>c=='1').Count()%2==0;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xagMxEERr6yu2CZbAEY5TKrrGJFUMBgdchBSKLC4L512yqzsw5r79cjiNpxuY95isj5mlTL0itXC4aC3nYO6bf0f6DcbkLqnCXriVdIarWWhNFTMMjCfYJSSrVWbs8wuStOrmCdzlraf8glRX8M3cNYD6OmAHESaKzVVK7YVgyzQUqf6DDzeXpdXG@eNPkWJzbHKMy6el81vuqVr3sIlxHcYwLWZOuSv@KFjL/LfYf719di7cboxmnP4A)

Comment: A few tips: **`.Where(c=>c=='1')`** you can save 1 byte by comparing if `c` is bigger than `'0'`, and you can save another byte by changing `'0'` to the decimal representation `48`. One more byte can be saved on **`.Count()%2==0`** by comparing if the result is less than `1`, resulting in this solution: `n=>{return Convert.ToString(n,2).Where(c=>c>48).Count()%2<1;};`

Comment: Also, you can save more 8 bytes by moving the predicate from `Where` to `Count` and removing the `Where` completely. Your solution would end up like this `n=>{return Convert.ToString(n,2).Count(c=>c>48)%2<1;};` for a total of 54 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), 29 bytes

`f(a){a=!__builtin_parity(a);}`

Uses a GCC builtin, and exploits how GCC handles return values, only works at `-O0` optimization level (the default).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z9NI1GzOtFWMT4@qTQzpyQzL74gsSizpBIobF37PzcxM09Ds5pLQaGgKDOvJE1DSUHBWEHXTkE1JSZPSUchTcNYU9MaWdrQEEXa0BBV3tzcHEUeyEczwATVfBN0C0xNUeRNTUHytf8B)

Answer (score 2):

## Lua 5.3.4, <s>63</s> 62 bytes

*-1 bytes thanks to Jo King*

```
function e(n)o=0while n>0 do o=o+n n=n//2 end return o%2<1 end
```

More readable version:

```
function e(n)
  o=0
  while n>0 do
    o=o+n
    n=n//2
  end
  return o%2<1
end
```

`n` is the input and integer divided by 2 until it is equal to 0. `o` is incremented by `n`, and its parity is what determines the output. This function returns true if evil or false if odious (not evil).

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

Can't believe there's no CJam/GolfScript answer yet.

```
qi2b1e=1&!
```

[Try it out! (Online)](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qi2b1e%3D2%250%3D&input=503)

---

**Explanation**

```
qi                     Reads input as an integer
  2b                   Converts it to an array of its digits in base 2 (binary)
    1e=                Checks the number of occurrences of 1 in that array
       1&              The rightmost bit of the number of 1s (a test for evenness)
         !             Unfortunately we need to return 1 for evenness and not 0 (and vice versa)
                       Implicit output 1 for true and 0 for false
```

---

This answer isn't very good in comparison to other answers here, but I might as well post and see if some CJam people can help golf this answer further.

---

#### Changes:

[Helen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58707/helen) cut off 2 bytes!

Old: `qi2b1e=2%0={1}0?`
New: `qi2b1e=2%0=X0?`

By replacing the block (`{1}`) with `X` (whose value is always initialised to 1) we can cut out 2 characters and don't have to add in any whitespace.
The If-Else still works without the block, funnily enough.

---

[Helen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58707/helen) cut off 3 bytes!

Old: `qi2b1e=2%0=X0?`
New: `qi2b1e=2%0=`

We don't need to manually push `1` and `0` to the stack depending on the result of the comparison since `1`/`0` are automatically pushed for `true`/`false` respectively.

---

[Helen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58707/helen) cut off 1 byte!

Old: `qi2b1e=2%0=`
New: `qi2b1e=1&!`

By keeping the rightmost bit of the number, we can test for evenness without having to use modulo.

Answer (score 2):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), <s>117 105 99</s> 93 bytes

```
_->In_a+s
a+0z->z
a+z+0c->b
z+0a+0c+f->
z+0a+0c+0f->f
b+0a+0z->c
c+0b->a
0a+0b+0c+0z+s->Out_f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYoxDoAgDEX3XqVpggtjdyePQAAlmqiYgAuHt1YGp/ffy/d7XJdjK1XEEY@n81jAo2nETdnQROIASo0RE/G/jUqC0E3vETQFYg9fCP3RsBBPd3VJxFr75Ktu@SxC8/AC)

Trying out BMO's new language! Outputs `0` if the number is evil and `1` otherwise. It took me quite a while to figure out how to check if there is only one of an atom left.

#### Explanation:

```
Input
_->In_a+s     Convert the initial _ atom to input copies of atom a
              And an s atom as a flag
Division
a+0z->z       Always have one z atom by converting an a atom
a+z+0c->b     Convert an a atom and a z atom to a b atom
              This divides the a atoms by 2 into b atoms
              With a z atom as the parity
z+0a+0c+0f->f Convert the z atom to an f atom if there aren't any f atoms
z+0a+0c+f->   If there is an f atom, remove both

Reset to calculate the next binary digit
b+0a+0z->c    Convert all b atoms to c atoms
c+0b->a       Convert all c atoms to a atoms

Output
0a+0b+0c+0z+s->Out_f  If there are no relevant atoms left
                      Output the number of f atoms
```

Comment: wow, nice. also, [close :(](https://tio.run/##JcsxDoAgDAXQnas0TXBxZHfyCISoiSRSTMAEOLyV4vZ@f7@7tvMIPmVmi2YhWyCAUwEK6IomQB0ebJ26G7RDQ@NrREm/ZUKKoElfOvqpyVSs/7A@2Trm@Y139pES4z59)

Comment: also -1 nondeterministic :P

Comment: Also, haha, we came up with the same solution of checking for 1

Comment: [:D tie, if it works](https://tio.run/##JcwxCsMwDIXh3Vd5CEyGjt479QhGtIEEaqdgB2QfvorlbB8/euLve1vTXqpqpPDMUZDALkHgG4WENj3ZB71QyC6jwfPQODXzHX1DtyjmDrHRtD0bhcLrrJFVH//jV/cjF6XPcgE). as an added bonus, it's deterministic

Comment: @ASCII-only i had a leftover unnecessary term, so `-3` bytes `:)`. I was wondering what was non-deterministic, but it turns out the `d+0f->f` rule goes off whenever it wants. Still technically deterministic since it doesn't affect anything

Comment: well. if i invert output then [103](https://tio.run/##JczBCoAgEIThe68yLBjdvXfqEWSpoCAtyGD14dvUbh8/zPAxb6vf76jqyI7BCXznITCJrEdqbsyFRsiGLiDBcBG4mf9oEnKNUp0hddRcz0ohOz3RsWo/vOcV9zPcSkv/AQ) :P, and [99](https://tio.run/##JczBCoAgEATQe7@yCEp37536BFkqSGg10MD149vUTvNmDoPXdh7kUxZxyi7BFaCJoIBmZQl4eLA26qJsmAIwaGwCHMZ/1Ay1j6W7iXr2o9HWJzsUMfMb7@xjSKJ28wE) without determinism

Comment: I see though that you don't use BMO's method of having a state atom. Also, you might wanna check if aliasing (e.g. `a+0c->g`) makes it shorter

Comment: I've sort of been winging it? The non-deterministic routes remind me a bit of Lost

Comment: Haha, yeah. I'm sure BMO has been winging it too lol

Comment: Darn, tie again :P

Comment: @ASCII-only You can switch most rules with `flag1 + ... -> flag1 + ...` to `0flag2 + ... -> ...` to save a byte for each rule affected. [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYzLCoQwDEX3/ZUQiLjP3tV8QgmjoGDSATvQ@vHG@lidc8/iyvqdJ1227B6RB4sFNJBBAarI9dFme1CggmyBFCqQIEuwZvI2qrAjl9aoUS9eH/f6/HMU964/0i8vyTbHsTsB)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88994/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-jo-king).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
b1¢È
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/yfDQosMd//@bmZkBAA)

Converts to binary `b`, counts occurrences of 1 `1¢`, and checks if it's even `È`.

Comment: I did something similar but to get counts of 1 I used S to make it a list and O to sum the list: bSOÈ

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 41 bytes

```forth
: f 1 swap 63 for 0 d2* m+ next + 2 mod ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRgqFJcnFiiYGSsABRUMFFKMtBRytRXyUitKFLQVjBRy81MUrP@rGhoaGgAhUIMelyqYCeH8BwA)

A function with signature `( u -- 0-or-1 )`, that is, one that takes a cell-sized integer from the stack and gives a 0 (not evil) or 1 (evil) on the stack. gforth's native boolean is -1 (true) and 0 (false), but any nonzero value is recognized as true, just like many other languages.

Unlike [the answer to a very similar challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194276/78410), the FP trick seems to fail to save bytes here.

#### How it works

```forth
: f ( u -- 0-or-1 ) \ Declare function f
  1 swap 63 for     \ Store a 1 under u, and loop 64 times ( 1 u )
                    \ The 1 is bit-count + 1
    0               \   Push a 0 (i.e. cast to unsigned double-cell int)
    d2*             \   Shift double-cell int left once ( 1 u' 0-or-1 )
                    \   In effect, shift MSB of u into the top
    m+              \   Add double [1 u'] and single [0-or-1]
                    \   In effect, add the bit to the bit-count
  next              \ End loop ( bc+1 0 )
  + 2 mod           \ Remove the dummy 0 at the top, and take modulo 2
;
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [8 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
›1¢|▬║~Ô
```

## Explained

Unpacked: `!(+\(:_b%2`

```
! Boolean not
  ( Expression
    +\ Fold with addition
      ( Expression
        :_ Format implicit variable _ (initialized as stdin)...
          b ... to binary
        %2 Modulo 2
      ) Implicit, can be removed
  ) Implicit, can be removed
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```scala
_.toBinaryString.sum%2<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM1VlpijkGal4JlXomBrp@CUn5@TmpinYPs/Xq8k3ykzL7GoMrikKDMvXa@4NFfVyMbwfwGQV5KTp5GmYaypyYXgGRqicM3NzVH4JqiqTU1RuGZmZkB@7X8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s><sup>5</sup></s> 4 bytes

```
¬F≠ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9Aat0edCx7u6P7//7@ZmRkA)

-1 byte from Jo King.

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 47 bytes

```
(load library)
(d E(q((N)(even?(sum(to-base 2 N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcorEoAgAAXA7ilefASDohBNVO@AA4EZ/AE6w@nRzVvCUWPIV2uMp3WIYUs2VdHRwfAmV0H/@mNhfnaWs99s9hixto67vWDwJ4lhgNYak8Q8QyklRPsA)

Straightforward solution, thanks to useful `library` functions.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.10, 25 bytes

```py
lambda x:~x.bit_count()%2
```

It's the same number of char that [Lynn's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169873/112099) but with a totally "new idea".
The `.bit_count()` is new in Python 3.10 and returns the number of 1.
So with that, you can make it 25 bytes.

Note: I can't put a "Try It Online" because their version of Python is 3.7.8
But thank's to [@pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)'s comment:
 [You can test the code here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuha702xzEnOTUhIVKqzqKvSSMkvik_NL80o0NFWNICpuKqblFylkKmTmKRQl5qWnahgaGGhaFRRlAhVl6qRpZGpqQhTCjAQA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: [My TIO alternative, ATO, has Python 3.10](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?L=python)

Answer (score 2):

### Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 27 bytes

This is my first ever post on code golf, and I am doing this mostly to hone my Mathematica skills. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
2∣Tr[IntegerDigits[#,2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73@hRx@KQomjPvJLU9NQil8z0zJLiaGUdo9hYtf8BRZl5JQ4hiUk5qdFp0ZmxOtWZOgY6hgYGtbH/AQ)

This works by checking the parity of the base-2 digit sum (also called the digital sum). The method is slightly different than the other Mathematica answers.

Edit: I was able to save three bytes by changing Total -> Tr. This was found in the tips page suggested in the comments.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for Golfing in Mathematica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12900) page for further ways you may be able to golf your code!

Comment: Thank you for the tips page. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 22 bytes

```
> +
|\<:
:&%!@
/<2
2 :
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/305Bm6smxsaKy0pNVdGBS9/GiMtIwer/f0OD/7opAA)

```
<
%!@   Output 1 if the result of `<` is divisible by 2, 0 otherwise...
2

 \    Recursive call:
:&    set current value to input value, or
/<    the previous value divided by 2
2

   :
 > +
:| <  If the current value is 0, return current (0);
 :    otherwise add the current value to the result of recursive call
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
BS2ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98p2Ojhjt7///@bGAMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 81 bytes

```vb
Input""n
s$=Bin$(n)
v=1
For i=1To Len(s$)
If Mid$(s$,i,1)="1"Then v=!v Fi
Next
?v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3zOvoLRESSmPq1jF1ikzT0UjT5OrzNaQyy2/SCHT1jAkX8EnNU@jWEWTyzNNwTczRQXI1snUMdS0VTJUCslIzVMos1UsU3DL5PJLrSjhsi/7/9/c3BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
§10Σ↨Ｎ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMOxxDMvJbVCQ8nQQElHIbg0V8MpsThVwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NHwUgTCKz//zc3N/@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     Ｎ  Input number
    ↨ ² Convert to base 2
   Σ    Sum of digits
§10     Cyclically index into literal string `10`
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 22 bytes

```
 ABCDEFGHe
a{{{{{{{{*f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/X8HRydnF1c3dI5UrsRoKtNL@/zdPSExKdgBKAgA)

Chip works in bytes, so each byte of input here is treated independently (which makes for easy test suites). The first byte is ASCII 7 (decimal 55), then 96 -> 99 and 64 -> 67.

This simply XOR's all the input bits, `A`-`H`, together (with an extra 1 to invert the result), and sets the low output bit, `a`, to the outcome. Output bits `e` and `f` are also set, making the program output be ASCII 0 for not-evil, and ASCII 1 for evil.

The right-to-left XOR's (`{`) can be replaced by right-to-left half adders (`@`) for the same result.

Comment: Interesting language. It looks like the input is treated as 7-bit ASCII, so you can probably save 2 bytes by removing `H` and its corresponding `{`.

Comment: @sundar Thanks! Input is easily given as ASCII, but it actually just sees raw bytes. Any control characters, or values above 0x7f are had to express in TIO, but they do work just fine. [For example, the unicode smile face is treated as the three independent bytes.](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/X8HRydnF1c3dI5UrsRoKtNL@/380YxcA)

Comment: Ah, it looks like the input characters (at least on [TIO](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/X8HRydnF1c3dI5UrsRoKtNL@/z@8BAA "Chip – Try It Online")) are treated as their UTF-8 encoded bytes. Then I guess the non-terminal bytes *can* have their high bit set. Just curious, since you said "hard to express in TIO", is there a way to input values above 0x7f by themselves on a local interpreter? On TIO it seems possible only as part of a multibyte character (for eg., to enter 0xe4, I have to input 䀀 (UTF-8 bytes 0xe4, 0x80, 0x80) and ignore the last two outputs).

Comment: The input scheme is quite beyond the point of the language, so sorry if this seems like bikeshedding, but it seems like an extended ASCII code like ISO-8859-1 (/Windows 1252) would make more sense for input for this language, making it easier to input byte values and allowing all byte values in input (for eg. I think the current method can't take 255 as input, since bytes with values 245 - 255 are not valid UTF-8 bytes in any character).

Comment: @sundar No worries! The interpreter just uses a binary input stream, so encoding isn't  even taken into account. On a command line, for example, I usually do something like `printf '\xe4' | ./chip [...]`, though input direct from a file would work too. ASCII, in the case of this example, is purely an external consideration, a way to provide a specific set of bits in a convenient (if incomplete) way.

Comment: Oh, and regarding the difficulty in TIO, it doesn't currently interpret escape sequences like `\xe4` in any special way. You'd have to [do something clever with a heredoc](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYGOj4OrvpmCnAOToJWdkFvx3TExyck5OcXFNTXNzT8/w@A@U5@IqKMrMK0lTUI@pSDVRV6hR0M8vKNEHqQcTegWVcAOAkhUVKf8B) or similar instead.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I've missed playing around with simple chips and circuits, and this language seems like it captures the feel of that pretty well, so I'll definitely be checking out more of it later.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>97</s> <s>64</s> <s>42</s> 39 Bytes

Thanks ilkkachu

```
(($(bc<<<obase=2\;$1|tr -d 0|wc -c)%2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X0NDRSMp2cbGJj8psTjV1ijGWsWwpqRIQTdFwaCmPFlBN1lT1UhT8////4aGAA)

Comment: Welcome to code-golf!  There is quite a lot you can do here to shorten this - `dc` expressions are generally shorter than `bc` - returning True/False in a shell return code is OK - no need to do `&& echo false || echo true`.  [Here is my shell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169787/11259).  Some good tips [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Thanks.  I shortened it up some, still not as short as yours though.

Comment: Doesn't that give an inverted return code? (Considering the common shell custom that zero is truthy) You could save one character by escaping just the semicolon, and a couple by replacing the variable with `wc -c`: `(($(bc<<<obase=2\;$1|tr -d 0|wc -c)%2))` (That also changes the return value so it returns 0 for even number of ones).

Answer (score 1):

## EXCEL, 106 bytes

applied Sir [Taosique's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388218/8343981) answer to handle larger numbers.

```
=ISEVEN(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(A1,256^1),256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(A1,256^0),256),8),0,)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ḃ+%₂0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GOZm3VR01NBv//m5ub/wcA)

#### Explanation

```
ḃ       Take the binary representation of the input
 +      Sum the digits
  %₂0   This sum modulo 2 is 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 21 bytes

```
n->1-sumdigits(n,2)%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoAgEADAryxCoLAetMRTfSQ6CKEItSxqh15vdpvhULJO3COsnfRmdH3uM6fcqiS0arI9MF@vJNAbcMnUBsUfAVGSUgj7jGAMgvceYRlx7lD9Aw)

Comment: +1. Beats the faster `n->1-hammingweight(n)%2`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
f n=even.sum$mapM(pure[0,1])[1..n]!!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcmxCsMgFEbh3ae4gQwJFKmkwSVOnfsEIRShN61U/4iavr5Jh8M3nI/NX/a@1pVg@MeQeQ9tsPHRxT3xfL2opZ@VlFiaBjVYBzL0/0/qYnIoJGk9S2xf/al34ExmmujN5b6hMEqug1BKaK3FbRDjeAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 30 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(x)(evenp(logcount x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBDoAgDMDuvoLjxlU/NGEYkgELguH3iInHpq2TeOsEz0GpUuLG1djQs7MThNLpCQYCP5wVpFyu9NzMQMSJ2wZa40L4ehL5R3PsS78)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>28</s> 22 bytes

**-6 bytes thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)**

```
:?!v:2%:@-$?:2,
%2l<;n
```

Code: 22 bytes
Input: put onto the stack using the `-v` command line argument
Output: 0 means not evil, 1 means evil

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38pesczKSNXKQVfF3spIh0vVKMfGOu////@6ZQqmpgA)

### Pseudocode

This is a highly abstracted summary of what the program does.
The interpreter puts the input value into `n` at startup.

```
l := 1

while n ≠ 0 do:
  m := n mod 2
  if m ≠ 0 then:
    l := l + 1
  n := (n - m) / 2

print l mod 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 104 bytes

```
+>,[++++>-[<->-----],]<[[-[[<]<]++++++++++<]<<[<,+<]++[->>]>,>[<<]>[>]<]<<<+[<[-<<+>>]<]<+[[<]++[->]<]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYuxCoBADEM/qK3rLSE/EjqoIIjgIPj95/UG3xJe0m7Pet7Hu1@9G102YAjBKNITUkhIpP0Mg@BWnYJMOgUkxawNJihGcLrV/7wsW3pvrX0)

Outputs a null byte for false, 0x1 for true. Uses the convert to binary trick twice, once to get the sum of binary digits and the other to check if that number is even or odd by getting the last binary digit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 33 bytes

```perl
sub e{pop=~//;$'?$'%2!=e($'/2):1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhtbogv8C2Tl/fWkXdXkVd1UjRNlVDRV3fSNPKsPZ/QVFmXomCtrZKpo6Sgkp8TJ6SQlp@kUJ6UWqBAlBZvKaOgZ6esYH1fwA)

Different approach, one byte longer:

```perl
sub e{(grep$_[0]&2**$_,0..31)%2^1}
```

Answer (score 1):

## perl -E, 39 bytes

```
say!((unpack"b*",pack I,pop)=~y/1/1/%2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 23 bytes

```
&#2:_v#:/
v#:\+<_
_2%.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X03ZyCq@TNlKnwtIxGjbxHPFG6nqOfz/b2oKAA)

Outputs `1` for non-evil, `0` for evil numbers. Calculates the parity of the sum of `n` divided by 2 repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```rust
|x:u64|!x.count_ones()%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczRCoIwFAbg@z3Fr5BscAhMbWD0JBER4mBgZzI3EOaefUX3H5@PWyiG8XlblgpJLHOAiTzhXo59jNf@qPbz5CKHl@N5k@p0KTdhnEdjYRnNo/shQtsStNaEYSD03RNp9ZbDwpWsU8aIlGuCpX8urVJZ5PIF)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
Ħ⁺2%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yLJHjbuMVP//NwYA)

Explanation:

```
      Implicit input
Ħ     Convert into binary and count the 1s
 ⁺    Increment
  2%  Mod 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <strike>13</strike> 12 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to ngn*

```
~2!+/(99#2)\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/38DWSFFbX8PSUtlIM8bMzOz/fwA)

Comment: `0=` -> `~`­­­­

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <strike>55</strike> 52 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @mazzy

```
1-([Convert]::ToString("$args",2)-replace0).Length%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtdC4IwFIbv9yuGzNhgRloqCEIQdNVd3kWE1FGDMW3OCszfbsO@7Fy973OetypvoOoChOhJFre969DdqpRXUHofRUm51eosc2qRVOW1xT3mKKhEeoQZm25A5rqwvb5DS4o4nXNMEtUAM9kfZdc1ZZ2KemhhGI5@i7@RPxaDIPhVhh/Yxi3C5ojkBO4VHDWccIzJ4UUV1I3QBkxIZpwBWoS@uQOX74hFH9tCXf8E)

Takes input as an integer from a command-line parameter.

Comment: :) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtdC4IwFIbv9yuGzNhgRloqCEIQdNVd3kWE1FGDMW3OCszfbsO@7Fy973OetypvoOoChOhJFre969DdqpRXUHofRUm51eosc2qRVOW1xT3mKKhEeoQZm25A5rqwvb5DS4o4nXNMEtUAM9kfZdc1ZZ2KemhhGI5@i7@RPxaDIPhVhh/Yxi3C5ojkBO4VHDWccIzJ4UUV1I3QBkxIZpwBWoS@uQOX74hFH9tCXf8E "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 44 bytes

```powershell
param($n)for(;$n;$n=$n-shr1){$e+=$n%2}1-$e%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvLDoIwEEX3/YoJGUwbYVEUSDQkrvwC94boEBa1YAvRBPn22uALJ7OYc@betrmRsTUp5bAqBteWprxw1KJqDN@i9lugjm1tpBiQlh7CZJQxUpi4ke04i/gqAjyYnoS/09ktpYd9qexEeZ7Pfuu/UjoPZln2QwEPCGFg4Ad1hHRv6dTRGQrA48sasr3qvFhg5TOTDJC/fUzXb0lsPumAje4J)

Straightforward counting.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 76 bytes

```
{({<([()]{})>{(<([()]{})>)()}{}}<(()[[]]{}){<>([(){}])(<><{}>)}{}>)}<>({}())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYoxDoAwDAO/Yw9MMEb5SJWhDEgIxMBq5e2hnVhO1vn2t5/Pctz9qhJkaGAo6cK/CaYyDWBrMZXM56sMwtyUPouB4ZUgq7b1Aw)

### Explanation

```
{
  ({ Divide by two
    <([()]{})>
    {(<([()]{})>)()}{}
  }
  # Invert other side if 1 is the next digit
  <(()[[]]{}){<>([(){}])(<><{}>)}{}>)
}
<>({}()) # Process output
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 29 chars, 58 bytes

```
{⍵≤0:0⋄∼2∣+/{(2⍴⍨⌊1+2⍟⍵)⊤⍵}⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{⍵≤0:0⋄∼2∣+/{(2⍴⍨⌊1+2⍟⍵)⊤⍵}⍵}
  f 3
1
  f 11
0
  f 777
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 53 bytes

```
=e(n)
~temp o=0
-(i)~o+=n%2
~n=n/2
{n:->i}{1-o%2}->->
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/q9rl6phrKlrp6CvrxBSVJrKBRIwNISKuCXmFEOEzM3N0VWZYOgzNcXQZ2Zmhiz23zZVI0@Tq64kNbdAId/WgEtXI1OzLl/bNk/ViKsuzzZP34irOs9K1y6zttpQN1/VqFbXTtfu/38A)

Counts bits.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 13 bytes

```
2 base{+}*2%!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlv@t9IISmxOLVau1bLSFXx/38A)

This can't really be golfed much harder in this language, I don't believe. Maybe a character somewhere? But you absolutely *need* to use "2 base", and that takes up half the program, which stinks. I did find a second, different solution though -

```
2 base[1]/,2%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlv/t9IISmxODXaMFZfx0j1/38A)

Here's the explanation for both;

```
2 base        #Convert into binary
#--------------------------#
      {+}*    #Add up all the 1s and 0s
          2%  #Mod 2
            ! #If even, make 1. If odd, make 0.
#--------------------------#
      [1]/    #Divide the binary across the 1s, this leaves 1 more array than the number of 1s
          ,   #Count the off-by-one array
           2% #If it mods to 1, it's even (because off by one), if not, it's 0. Neat!
```

If I could say "0 is truthy, and 1 is falsy", then I could save a character on the first one, but that would just be silly!

Comment: This gives an error for input 0

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlv8N9IISmxOLVau1bLSFXx/38A "GolfScript – Try It Online") - are you putting it in "input" or "header"? Header is where GS takes in input - straight into the stack.

Comment: That was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
bSOÈ
```

Explanation:

```
bS    # Takes the input and coverts it into a list of binary digits
  O   # Sums all of the digits in this list
   È  # Checks if the sum is even
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Kdj/cMf//4amAA)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Kevin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169726/6484).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

```python
lambda n:bin(n).count('1')%2<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKikzTyNPUy85vzSvREPdUF1T1cjW1uB/um20sY6hoY65ubmOibGOqamOmZlZLFdafpFCpkJmnkK6FZdCQVEmUE@aRqam5n8A)

Thanks to @Stephen for saving a byte!

Comment: You can save a byte with `<1` instead of `==0`.

Comment: ...`lambda n:~bin(n).count('1')%2` would save one more (still not gonna beat `lambda n:int(bin(n),13)%2` though :))

Comment: You can also do `lambda x:~x.bit_count()%2` which is shorter

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>29</s> <s>28</s> <s>26</s> <s>64</s> <s>63</s> 49bytes

```
static boolean c(int r){return r==0||c(r*2)^r<0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/JCoMwEIbvPsXgKalUtAtCrY/Qk8cuEBdKbIySjEJRn92mEqidw8A3y//PVKxn26p4zW2XCZ5DLpjWcGFcwjBrZGhqWdOIkknICZcIig6qxE5JUEkSjGNO1GZHH@ocxNMMYHXsat/wAmqjRlJUXD6vd2B0cMAElhrJnsY/CMM1RVG0xsPf6PG40OSYtLZamt8ruXVJ3xrL2m869FtzAApJuOeebuh65h1qVab5Aw)

Seems to work. Nice bit of recursion. <s>It'd be <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 23 if I could rename the outer class. Perhaps get a better reference to itself.</s>

Old and boring saves 14 bytes, by Jo King. (If you really want traditional and do-it-by-hand `r->0<((r=(r=(r=(r^=r<<16)^r<<8)^r<<4)^r*4)^r*2)` for 47 (may have the odd byte of flab).

Comment: @JoKing I don't have a knowledge of all the meta posts the rules are covered on.

Answer (score 1):

## C([GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)), 33 bytes

```c
f(n){return!__builtin_parity(n);}
```

Uses a compiler builtin, and as such works only with GCC and clang and whatever other compiler that implements it. Appears to work with all optimization settings.

[Try it online! - GCC](https://tio.run/##jc7RCoIwFAbg63qK0yDYoJCh2yAvfJFATDQGdpQ5AxGffS26ci3oXP6Hj/@vz/e6dq6lyBbT2MngoSxvk@6sxnKojLazf@Wre1QaKYNlvxuMRttSokdIoXnqroDjeEVygpamDAogczMSuADBnrAc3pck4MON5TzEnEe1t9hvqFIqtErFbKQ2@9qcpb9qQytEaIX4c7KUMrQ@iuAPXd0L)

[Try it online! - clang](https://tio.run/##jc7RCoIwFAbg63qK0yDYoJCh2yAvfJFATDQGdpQ5AxGffS26ci3oXP6Hj/@vz3VX4d25liJbTGMng4eyvE26sxrLoTLazv6Vr@5RaaQMlv1uMBptS4keIYXmqbsCjuMVyQlamjIogMzNSOACBHvCcnhfkoAPN5bzEHMe1d5iv6FKqdAqFbOR2uxrc5b@qg2tEKEV4s/JUsrQ@iiCP3R1Lw)

Comment: You can abuse GCC's register placement to avoid the `return` (see [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067)): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc7RCoIwGAXg63qKv0GwQSFDt0ESvkggJho/2K@oBSI@@1p05VrQuTzwcU55vJWltTUnMdN5l@fXBzYjUt4VPY6Tq9PF3gskLmDebroeaaw5wwFiqJ7YZLAfLsQOUPNYQAZsqgYGJ2DUMpHCO1EErlxZKX0sZVA7S@2KGmN8a0zIBmaTr89J/GvWt0r5Vqk/L2utfeuqAP7Qxb4A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/index.html), 13 bytes

```
~2base{},,2%!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84oKbE4tbpWR8dIVfH/fzMzMwA)

`~`: turn input string into an integer

`2base`: turn top of stack into base two (represented by an array of 1s and 0s)

`{},`: filter out all 0s; the `,` command consumes the array and a code block (`{}`) and pushes an array containing only the elements for which the codeblock evaluates positivly (the 1s)

`,`: the top of stack is an array, so `,` consumes the array and pushes the length of the array

`2%!`: push `2`, get the modulus(`%`) of the length and 2, and invert(`!`) the result

when the program halts, the stack is dumped into stdout, this results in either `1` for true or `0` for false

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](http://desmos.com/calculator), <s>251</s> <s>201</s> <s>197</s> <s>178</s> 79 bytes

Wow... Coming back to this after months, and finding the most obvious golfs... lol

```
a=[0,...floor(\log_2N)]
f(N)=\{\mod(\total(\floor(\mod(N,2^a2)/2^a)),2)=0:1,0\}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pgm2aousqo)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xva1ywlzzw)

Comment: u dont need the comma before `...`

Comment: and u can call `\total` with dot notation

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```rust
|n|n.count_ones()%2<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZnZNaopBmlZankWlspKlrl5Sfn6Ng@78mryZPLzm/NK8kPj8vtVhDU9XIxvC/tQJXYnFxalFJfGqhokZaYk5xqk6ahpmZmaamNbJMSVEpWMIQh4QxdmFzc3OQRO1/AA)

Nothing fancy going on here, just counting the ones of the input then checking if it is even.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>10</s> 3 bytes

```
b∑₂
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=b%E2%88%91%E2%82%82&inputs=3&header=&footer=)

```
b∑  # Sum of binary digits
  ₂ # Is even?
```

Comment: [3 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=b%E2%88%91%E2%82%82&inputs=3&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 12 bytes (3 instrs)

```
00000000: db000000 7f000001 f8010000           ṃ¡¡¡¶¡¡¢ẏ¢¡¡
```

```
isevil  SADD $0,$0,0
        ZSEV $0,$0,1
        POP  1,0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 19 bytes

```
[ bit-count even? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxDoIwFEV3vuKGhFETUoFEo47GxcU4IQOWhzRKW8urxhi/HSvjuTn3tLVk48bTcX/YLdEa19fMSl9xI6fpjoDd/KL4pQaaANYR89s6pRkDPTxpSQNWUfSBQJqiKAosBLIMeZ7jO5YI95k0Pvj0JL1FFbbGW1T/ljUhXCJORIP1Bok/6xhTvQ2CNP0kUC278Qc)

Should be self-explanatory, I hope.

Comment: tfw not a native english speaker

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html), 10 bytes

```
!%/.BQ"1"2
```

[Try it online!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%21%25%2F.BQ%221%222&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A11%0A777%0A43%0A55%0A666&debug=0)

Trying to learn Pyth, so this is my go at it.
How it works:

Convert the input to binary, count the number of "1"s, check whether they're even, invert the output (so it checks whether they're odd. In more detail:

```
!                 # negate output (0 -> 1, 1 -> 0)
    %             # check whether the following block returns an even number
        /         # count string occurences in...
            .B    # ...the binary string version of...
                Q # ...the input
            "1"   # the string 1; the string to be count the occurences of
    2             # the 2 used by the modulo parity check
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.469 bytes

```
OSb
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJPU2IiLCI3NzciXQ==)

Outputs using inverted truthiness (`0` -> `true`, `1` -> `false`) because of a bug with `E`.

```
OSb
  b # To binary
 S  # Sum
O   # Is odd?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
%(1NTBa)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYrVDUM_UKcEjUhXKjo0mhzc_NYKAcA)

Outputs `0` for truthy and `1` for falsy.

### [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
!%(1NTBa)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYrFVU1DP1CnBI1IXyo8NJoc3PzWCgHAA)

Outputs `1` for truthy and `0` for falsy.

##### Explanation

```python
     TBa   # Convert input to binary
   1N      # Count 1s
 %(     )  # Mod 2
!          # Logical not
```

Comment: [6 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhbLVFW0Q5wSIRyo2NJoc3PzWCgHAA) (or 7 with `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃ1cE
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWyx7uaDZMdl1SnJRcDBVasNjc3BzCBAA)

**Explanation:** Is the `c`ount of `1`s in the `ḃ`inary representation `E`ven?

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 3 bytes

```
Ƃ∑½
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FsuPNT3qmHho75LipORiqNiCTcZchoZc5ubmXCbGXKamXGZmZhAZAA)

```
Ƃ∑½
Ƃ       Binary digits
 ∑      Sum
  ½     Check if it is even
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
!%/jQ2 1 2
assign('Q',eval_input())
imp_print(Pnot(mod(div(join(Q,2),(1)),(2))))
```

Simply converts a given input to binary as a list, and prints the logical not of the modulo 2 for the amount of 1's in that list.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, <s>62</s> <s>55</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 34 bytes

```swift
let e={($0+0).nonzeroBitCount%2<1}
```

Nothing particularly interesting here.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 18 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 2.25 bytes

```
b∑₂
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiYuKIkeKCgiIsIiIsIjQzIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
011100101011110000
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 3 bytes

```
b∑e
```

[Try it Online! (link is to literate version)](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJsIiwiIiwidG8tYmluYXJ5IHN1bSBldmVuPyIsIiIsIjQzIiwiMy40LjAiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 39 bytes

```cpp
=ISEVEN(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(BASE(A1,2),0,)))
```

The formula converts the number to base 2, removes all the zeros and checks if the LEN of the resulting string is even.

Comment: You have the same issue that I found, in that `0` returns a `true` value.

Comment: @ShaunBebbington, isn't that the expected result? 0 in binary representation is 0. So it has 0 1s. And 0 is an even number.

Comment: Yes, that's how I read it too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), <s>23</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
Ì£î␅␏MW¼R¥␕¼×_f|µ8
```

<sup>due to lack of unicode representations for c1 control characters, they have been replaced by their superscripted abbreviations</sup>

Decompressed:

```
f(}`(>+<))"[f]>f>-'
```

Explanation:

`f(       )`           declares function `f`

`` }`(   ) ``            right shifts byte at pointer and if the lost bit was a 1, it executes a lambda

`>+<`            increments the byte to the right of the pointer

`"`         takes in a 16 bit integer and XORs its bytes bitwise

`[f]>f>`   runs f until the byte at the pointer is 0, then runs f once on the byte to the right

`-'` decrements the byte once to flip its truthiness (0->255, 1->0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 15 bytes

```
[bits sum 2%0=]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/Pzops6RYobg0V8FI1cA29r@DVRoXlwaXgoIxEBsaAglzc3MgaQLim5pyaSpEK1gppCko6yioK@jaAYms/Mw8hfzSEoVYhdzEgv8A)

Checks whether or not the `sum` of the `bits` of the input mod 2 (`2%`) is `0` (`0=`).

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 58 bytes

```cs
n=>System.Convert.ToString(n,2).Replace("0","").Length%2<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5Na8JAEIbv@RVDoLAL6dpoQw5@XAqeLBQVPBQP23VMF7azZWcVpPjbY4yWCl7S9zrvM89r@NH4gLVxmhnekp8EmnDU0RoIqDee3AEWB474paY7MiNLMYMP790EtjCuaTy5Xl887TFEtfSLGCxVgrK@VHP8dtqgSJ/SLE2lmiFV8fOhP8pruGaY3Er33m7gVVsS3L55X4MOFcu2c5l3zp@UvUO1CjbizBKKrRhIOWwavR4sww67EHneIg0x1Y47IWVZnpl/SJ4Hv5KuRFHczzomx/oE)

I could do something similar to the Java answer with

```cs
n=>System.Convert.ToString(n,2).Sum(c=>c)%2<1
```

That's 45 bytes but then I would need to add another 18 for `using System.Linq;`. So I needed to find another approach.

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 57 bytes

```
func[n][s: on until[if n % 2 = 1[s: not s]1 > n: n / 2]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcqxCoAgFIXhvac4S3NYiSDUQ7TKnVJBiGukPr/VkG3fzzmXs3Vz1lDndfWFd8NkkkZkFM7hMMGD0WPEAvEOHDMSCazgJzBgpET1vAJneEzdJyEalVLN8/@Qst4)

Answer (score 0):

## [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_language), 35 bytes

```
e=1-mod(count(put(i,binary.),1),2);
```

This expression takes a variable `i` as input and populates the result in a new variable, `e`. It relies on implicit conversion from character to numeric when specifying which digit to count.

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 27 bytes

```
0sb[2~lb+sbd1<a]dsaxlb1++2%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b//foDgp2qguJ0m7OCnF0CYxNqU4sSInyVBb20j1f9p/c3NzAA)

Instead of accumulating the bits in register `b`, we can also leave them on the stack (replace `lb+sb` by `r`) which essentially converts the input to binary, push 1, sum the stack and do the mod 2. But it's the same byte-count:

```
[2~rd1<a]dsax1[+z1<a]dsax2%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b/8/2qiuKMXQJjE2pTixwjBauwrGNlL9n/bf1BQA)

### Explanation

Register `b = 0`, *divmod* on ToS, add remainder to `b` and loop until ToS is less or equal to 1, then compute `ToS + b + 1 mod 2`:

```
0sb[2~lb+sbd1<a]dsaxlb1++2%  # example input 5                     |  stack
0sb                          # initialize register b with 0        |  5
   [2~lb+sbd1<a]             # push the string [..]                |  [2~lb+sbd1<a]
                dsa          # duplicate & store it to register a  |  [2~lb+sbd1<a]
                   x         # execute the string*                 |  1
                    lb       # push register b                     |  1 1
                      1+     # increment by 1                      |  2 1
                        +    # add                                 |  3
                         2%  # modulo 2                            |  1

# Recursively called string:
2~lb+sbd1<a  # recursively called string   |  5
2~           # divmod 2                    |  1 2
  lb         # push register b             |  0 1 2
    +        # add                         |  1 2
     sb      # store register b            |  2
       d     # duplicate                   |  2 2
        1<   # if top (popped) is > 1:
          a  # | execute register a        |  2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, <strike>69</strike> <strike>53</strike> 39 bytes

```
print(bin(int(input())).count('1')%2<1)
```

Works by using the built in python binary to converter, `bin()`, on the input, then counts the number of ones in there, checks if it is equal to 0 mod 2, and prints the result (outputs True/False).

Probably needs some more golfing, but this was my first whirl.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@heather/test)

Comment: You can't assume inputs preassigned to a variable, though you can use a lambda: [`lambda x:1if len([i for i in bin(x)[2:]if i=='0'])%2==0else 0`](https://tio.run/##DckxDoAgEATAr2xjgA6xM7mXqAVEiJfgYZQCX49OO9dbjyJTT7T27M@we7R55IQcRS@MVG4wWBBYdDOLm7c/mUhZtZnBEdmYnwjbr5ulaiQ9GZj@AQ "Python 3 – Try It Online") which is shorter anyways (I included some basic golfing).

Comment: Some more golfing on your approach (using that `b` has a higher ascii-codepoint than `'0'`) leaves you with: [`lambda x:len([1for i in bin(x)if'0'<i])%2`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKic1TyPaMC2/SCFTITNPISkzT6NCMzNN3UDdJjNWU9Xov7KCsYKtnUJIUWkql7KCoSGI45aYUwzimZubI8mZICs0NUUo5IIbb6xjaKgD1KVjYqxjamrFpaBQUJSZV6KhkKaRqamg@R8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @OMᗺ you should probably post that as your own answer, as it's such a better approach than mine. I'd feel bad taking credit for it =)

Comment: I won't - [there](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169873/48198) [are](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169757/48198) already shorter ones, but your submission still uses a preassigned variable as input [which is not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/48198).

Comment: @OMᗺ fixed by switching to input()

Comment: @JoKing thank you, I have done so.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 39 bytes

```
readInt.toBinaryString.count('1'==)%2<1
```

[Try it online](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/z8Zz204/0)

This can be run in a Scala console, after which the user has to input the integer and press enter.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: This submission seems to be a snippet which is disallowed. Please change your submission to either a full program or a function definition.

Comment: Also, could you please make the title of your answer into a header (i.e. `# Scala, 34 bytes`) to fix the scoreboard?

Comment: @JonathanFrech I updated my answer, it now reads the input from user input, and is executable from the Scala console, or as a Scala script

Answer (score 0):

## Math++, 40 bytes

```
?>a
3+3*!a>$
b+a%2>b
_(a/2)>a
2>$
!(b%2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
def e(n:Int):Int=if(n>0)n%2^e(n/2)else 1
```

Test: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/VlU7nun/2

Comment: Could you please add a comma after `Scala` in the title of your answer so it doesn't break the scoreboard?

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 46 bytes

```
lambda n:sum(int(d)for d in str(bin(n))[2:])%2
```

Outputs `1` for True or `0` for false

Comment: You don't need to stringify the binary

Answer (score 0):

### MATLAB 31 bytes

Anonymous function, use as `f=@(n)...;f(3)`

```
@(n)1-mod(sum(dec2bin(n)-48),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>15</s> 10 bytes

```
qi2b1e=2%!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzDTKMkw1dZIVfH/f0MDAA)

```
Explanation
qi2b1e=2%! %whole code
qi         %Read input as number | Example stack: 10
  2b       %Convert to binary    | Example stack: 1010
    1e=    %Count ones           | Example stack: 22
       2%  %Mod 2                | Example stack: 0
         ! %Invert               | Example stack: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots), <s>86</s> 64 bytes

```
/{&}\
|(*)?#-. 
*{>}:@1({+}*@:-{%}$#&
*{+}\#1/.^-/.-#2/
\-*.<#1)
```

Returns 1 if the number is evil, otherwise 0. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxOzsxMyS8p/v9fv1qtNoarRkNL015ZV0@BS6vartbKwVCjWrtWy8FKt1q1VkVZDSiqXRujbKivF6err6erbKTPFaOrpWejbKj5/7@5uTkA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 84 bytes

```pascal
var n,s:word;begin read(n);repeat s:=n mod 2xor s;n:=n div 2until n=0;write(s=0)end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdJCoAwDADAr@SooCJeCpY@JpooBU1LUpffV5zbZLQVj37La603Kkhn85OU/MJ7FFBGaqT1ypmxgM1B4EwE05sUzMt/ijdMl5R4gITRPxoLNxbGloWGWp1zHw)

No conversion to binary :(

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 14 bytes

```
IW2SD@+$|~2%zh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/3zPcKNjFQVulps5ItQrINwYA)

Explanation:

```
IW2SD@+$|~2%zh  //Program for reference

I               //Input a integer
 W              //Loop until the number given is 0 (due to the int div 2 inside the loop)
  2SD           //  Push the div and mod of the remaining number by 2
     @          //  Rotate the top three elements on the stack (stack now is: curNumber/2, lastBitSet, bitCount)
      +         //  Add the bit count and the last bit flag
       $|       //  Swap the bitCount with the curNumer/2 and repeat until curNumber/2 == 0
         ~      //Remove the loop exit flag (0) 
          2%zh  //Check wether the bitCount is even, output & exit: 1 == truthy, 0 == falsy
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 14 bytes

```
2base{^}*!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlvaGD63ygpsTi1Oq5WS/H/fwA)

#### Explanation:

```
2base         convert input to binary
     {^}*     xor all bits
         !    flip answer
```

Comment: This appears to be only 10 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [chevron](https://ch.superloach.xyz/?inp=&src=Pjo-Xm4KXm4sMTAsMn54Pj5ebgpiXm4sMTN-eD4-Xm4KXm4lMj4-Xm4KPl5u), 45 bytes

method borrowed from Lynn's python answer.

```
>:>^n
^n,10,2~x>>^n
b^n,13~x>>^n
^n%2>>^n
>^n
```

notes:

- outputs `:0` for falsy and `:1` for truthy.
- online interpreter defaults to printing the input at prompts, uncheck "print inp" to disable.
- replace `:` with `^__` for no prompt.

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 11 bytes

```
~2base{^}*!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84oKbE4tTquVkvx/38zMzMA)

```
~2base        # Convert to binary
      {^}*    # Xor all the numbers in the array
          !   # Negate the output
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 7.4, 65 bytes

Input is given in $n

```
echo array_reduce(str_split(decbin($n)),fn($c,$i) => $i xor$c,1);
```

or prior to PHP 7.4: 76 bytes

```
echo array_reduce(str_split(decbin($n)),function($c,$i){return$i xor$c;},1);
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b93190e39d3c8a257ea493468495fb7b6ea3a55)

## Ungolfed

```
echo array_reduce(
    str_split(decbin($n)),
    function ($c,$i) {
        return $i xor $c;
    },
1);
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 70 bytes

```powershell
if(([convert]::tostring($args[0],2)-replace"0","").length%2){0}else{1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAv0iBQoXZza@Ih5BNhUVjlTqEb99m7voCtQSIzPmS0oVaHqDure21dcolyumk2Jz2i1ErwY1nAKHFIoTaEErsaTbq0wOwwbcPZj5@)

Sorry don't know if any powershell solution is posted, if so, I am ready to delete my submission.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda n:not f"{n:b}".count("1")&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHPKi@/RCFNqTrPKqlWSS85vzSvREPJUElTzfD/fwA)

Comment: You can do `lambda x:~x.bit_count()%2`

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 34 bytes

```python
lambda x:not bin(x).count('1')%2
```

Converts input to `bin`, then counts 1s, mod 2 (invert because of even=1)

[Try it online (Python 3.8.0b4)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PycxNyklUaHCKi@/RCEpM0@jQlMvOb80r0RD3VBdU9Xo/39jAA)

[Try it online (OLD) (Python 3.8.0b4)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8I2L79EISkzTyMzrwSIC0pLNDQ1NfWS80uBfHVDdU1Vo/8FRSDJCs3/xgA)

Comment: This looks like a snippet which just evaluates to the answer, which isn't one of our allowed output methods. You'd need to include `print()` around the expression in your answer, or convert your answer to a function, like `lambda x:not bin(x).count('1')%2`

Comment: You can do `lambda x:~x.bit_count()%2`

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 24 bytes

```swift
{$0.nonzeroBitCount%2<1}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DcexCoMwEAbg3af4kQrJYEi1k2gHnXwHlw4GDuSuxNNCxWePftu3/ijoK@2fiNDAjKwW5Ru9yIIuHQ/vWPg/R@lJB9lYi6p9nilIBIEY3jlXexwZbt9IrCafDFnQinmnpcFkwn2b2@xMFw)

Type information not included, since the argument can be any [`FixedWidthInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger). For example, all of the following are valid:

```swift
let f: (Int) -> Bool = {$0.nonzeroBitCount%2<1}
let g: (UInt64) -> Bool = {$0.nonzeroBitCount%2<1}
let h: (CChar) -> Bool = {$0.nonzeroBitCount%2<1}
```

Unlike many other C-family languages, integers cannot implicitly be converted into booleans, and characters cannot be implicitly converted to numbers, so the approaches taken by the top C++ and C# answers are too verbose.

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 26 bytes

```arturo
$=>[0=%∑digits.base:2&2]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?a7Oxzy)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
2b{^}*!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1v/N8oqTquVkvx/38A)

Port of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213726/114970) GolfScript answer, go upvote that!

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), <s>6</s> 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
/=⋯
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAgLz3ii68KCmYgMwpmIDExCmYgNzc3CmYgNDMKZiA1NQpmIDY2Ngo=)

```
/=⋯
  ⋯  # bits
/=   # reduce by equality
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 62 bytes

```go
import."math/bits"
func f(n uint)bool{return OnesCount(n)%2<1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDfSsMwFMbxcnmKY6GQQJ1M3SabnYh6q6K9U5GsJrNsTUp6Ckrok3hTBB_CR9GnMWknm1fnT77znV_O-8dCN18FT5d8ISDnmSJZXmiD_UDmGHxWKPeOv2d_vZzjy_48wzIgslIpSKqgyhSyudYrawRWRsG1EuW5rhRSxcKDk0HdufzsnOJbISCBEk2VIthMFe30FMRrAd6i7mw9B2VgCYoSS5jEcP-YWGIPI3Cjoo6IHQwikHxVtsV4PN68HG2phsMt1Wg02lQ1ITfG7V4pGsRxDHfJ2W0CLgsYkdrAU4R-r-HK3aXDsKTH07YrKfYdPCO9TIJeTmLs-x84GyeYwq5egoXWXtIgfIZ4BiECDZG5-KACB-jnIy_3uRuOnA-D2nH9w4LLqwtYY63v2DRd_AU)

Uses the `bits.OnesCount` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda n:not f"{n:b}".count("1")&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHPKi@/RCFNqTrPKqlWSS85vzSvREPJUElTzfD/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 28 + 1 = 29 bytes

*Added one byte for `-p` as per the scoring system when the question was asked.*

```perl
$_=(sprintf"%b",$_)=~y/1//%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lajuKAoM68kTUk1SUlHJV7Ttq5S31BfX9Xo/38zMzMuc3Pzf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA)

Outputs 0 for evil, 1 for not evil.

Answer (score 0):

## Commodore BASIC V2 (Commodore C64/VIC-20 and C128 in 64 mode, THEC64/THEC64 Mini, and some CBM/PET models) ~75 BASIC bytes

This listing should handle positive integers between `0` and `2147483647` inclusive, and meets all test conditions.

```
0 INPUTY:C=2^21:U=.
1 U=U-(Y>=C):Y=Y+(Y>=C)*C:C=C/2:ON-(C>=1)GOTO1:PRINT.=(UAND1)
```

Some notes: there is no error handling, nor does it check for integer-only numbers, so you may enter `3.14` and it will treat this as if you entered `3`. Also, using this method, entering `0` will show `-1` which in Commodore BASIC is `true`. I guess binary `0` has an even number of `1s` in its binary representation, as zero is even, and binary `0` has zero ones.

Where you see `.` this is a BASIC equivalent of `0`, but it is parsed faster by the interpreter.

[image: Is this number evil in Commodore BASIC on the Commodore C64]