# Computational Parity Party!

Tags: code-golf, bitwise

The computational parity of an integer is defined as 1 if the integer has an odd number of set bits, and 0 otherwise. ([src](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_function)).

### Input

- You will receive one nonnegative integer that you will take the parity of. Optionally, you may take the size of the integer in bytes or bits as an argument, but you must specify this in your answer.

### Output

- You will output the computational parity of the input integer.

### Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply, including but not limited to [Abusing native number types to trivialize a problem](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/89298).

### Test cases

You may omit any input that cannot be represented with your language's built-in integer type.

```
0: 0
1: 1
3: 0
8: 1
13: 1
17: 0
40: 0
52: 1
100: 1
127: 1
365: 0
787: 1
2898: 0
6345: 0
9038: 1
10921: 1
16067: 1
4105748: 1
40766838: 0
1336441507: 1
4294967295: 0
```

Generated using [this program](https://tio.run/##hVJNb8IwDL33V1ibBO0EUtOP9INSadtlu047TkMlLSxa26AmRdoQv50lKdBwWg6J47z37Ngmu918S8jpdE9bUvdlBRllXHRV0eTW6CM1bajguWWtGauBsGa32hUdFT9233K6basS9kXtWAcL5Lr6@BfrBKwlFZbA6W/FNrbCwQM8vzy@rZ5e3yHPAS0szduwzh7JTcG/Jc1GkGVaw4G5hGpz2CV3CWg2IJWtnY7WUkuGUgLqkFEGic/hPtEk5xy4q0TftQq/sI7/1GJfEcE6WQraCilCW3vPaHn5Ohdlmg6Q7PKTHETFBdfvh2ty7uxqotH0RzM2AIYbRaMdGCKhZ2BcU90zGD4Ox0sUGy9enBgRsR8YwMT1zWzcxDNSRtjFZk7IDaMgNpOMMI5vBHwfBwEKXZPmJUGCIy85hz0aM1H0gsFEQDoUcmywrjZhvVAjore7FO7UaY6ocJRn@tFOb9vtqmb/AQ).

The answer with the least amount of bytes in each language wins, which means that I will not be accepting an answer.

Bonus imaginary Internet points for an explanation.

[Sandbox link (10k+)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18532/89298)

Comment: I was pretty sure I already answered this before. I think it's actually a dupe of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/169724/58563). The only difference is that it's expecting the opposite output.

Comment: @Arnauld Expecting the opposite output does make a substantial difference in some of the answers, though.

Comment: Inverting the output is not really enough to justify a new challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>18</s>  17 bytes

Similar to [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169732/58563) to [Is this number evil?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/169724/58563) except that the last iteration returns \$0\$, which saves a byte.

```javascript
f=n=>n&&!f(n&~-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdJLDoIwEIDhvafATQMLZPqalgXehSAYDWmJGJdevUYTAq0N7frLP33d21c7d4/b9CyNvfTODY1pzoaQ45Ab8i5N4TprZjv2p9Fe8yGHosjWVVUZHHxAQ0ADwFMFnSpQLxEDKgDhCAEJIFlqBGwTMcDUPuAofRDuQelEgel6c1eRAnIhd0EN3C/8H7Nm64vGAAKqPSAoSCWWKTEAClEv@4j9KM5RCCrhN@dbcB8)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

Converts to binary, parses as base-3 and returns the parity.

```javascript
n=>parseInt(n.toString(2),3)&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdK7CoMwFIDhvU/hVAy0enKPg9079wnEqlgkEQ19fUsLokmDyfzxn9xe1bua66kf7VWbZ7O05aLL21hNc3PXNtWZNQ879bpLCbpQdMZLbfRshiYbTJe2KSCUbCvPEzi5APsAe4DGCipWwE4iBKQH/BEMIoCT2AjYJ0KAyGNABXeBvwepIgWiit1dBQqCMn4ICqBu4f@YBdleNAQECHkEGAYu2TolBEAKodZ9hH4UpYIxzOE351tYPg)

Comment: I think you moved your code up above the `lang` mark, so it's not getting syntax highlighting.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Seems like there's nothing to highlight in there, but fixed anyway. :-)

Comment: Hmm... That base 3 solution is interesting. Any chance that it could be implemented without converting to a string?

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
BSḂ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98p@OGOpv///xsDAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##HYyrEQJBDIZbSQER2bx2YzEUgGSQmJtr4OwZmqEABI6hEGgkZFH/N/9rua7rlnk4fR57vp@v23e/HzPPhNAQBGEUlLSOoGUaF9NMuRxxQ@ijiEdU00XLCJK5ouC6aE4@t42s65gn3X38CyKu2oxmzKHhncMuPw).

#### How?

```
BSḂ - Link: non-negative integer
B   - to binary
 S  - sum
  Ḃ - least-significant-bit
```

Comment: Interesting. +1 for the explanation.

Comment: `B^/` is another 3

Comment: On mobile it looks like BS[]. Stupid font encodings...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and 1-f(n&~-n)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU5LCsMgEN33FLMqEQyoo6MGepiUVBpoJyF1002vbsfM5j3ej9m/9bkxtlZur/l9X2bgiWHmBexYBr7@RlatbAfUx6fCyjAYDVYDakhCBGzU4EUMTrjprhMFKWiISZhLWZKEXoRssLdMdjJhyVDvWhOiT30kEqUzgEje22C67bLPFF0OarqA3H6sXIf@joZyolLtDw)**

This is quite nice because if we just want to *identify* the parity we can reduce it to **25 bytes** returning `0` or `-1`:

```python
f=lambda n:n and~f(n&~-n)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and n&1^f(n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5BCsMwDATvfYUuaRIQVJJt2Q70K4UUExpolRBy6etd97qzA7N/z9dmUutyf8@fZ5nBJoPZCtiVH8tgNxnrsh1gsBoQMjpMyA45oicMgkxtlYhOA8YUUVJOqM4HzOTalbIwspI2gSlEn5oYVdMfOqfec6DGJPusUXKYLgD7sdoJfVcm6ErfDYbQWsax/gA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 28 bytes

```
read*,i
print*,poppar(i)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vSk1M0dLJ5Cooyswr0dIpyC8oSCzSyNTkSs1L@f/f0NjYzMTE0NTAHAA)

Fortran has this as an in-built since F2008

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <strike>5</strike> 4 bytes

```
bSOÉ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Kdj/cOf//4bGxmYmJoamBub/AQ)

### Explanation

```
bSOÉ

b    # convert (implicit) input to base 2
  O  # the sum of...
 S   # the digits...
   É # is odd?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 4 bytes

```
ES2%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/9812Ej1////hmYGZuYA)

### Explanation

```
ES2%

 S    # the sum of...
E     # the binary digits...
  2%  # mod 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 19 bytes

```ruby
->n{("%b"%n).sum%2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtLCoMwEIavUoRAC39lJpPMJIv2IuKiLtwp0iJY1LOn6fZ7vNfhW8ZHuT/n/dq4oXHzrf2sk/Nn6QgMQQIL2BAI0YOpUm8QjbBk8CknqISITFJTyp7BSloHpmgh1dFU01@KaAgcqTqfQ1bzOfbt9Fr2YzuWS7dh7La@P8sP)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>34</s></sup> 21 bytes

Saved 13 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

```c
f(n){n=n&&!f(n&n-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZG7CsMwDEX3foUbSLAhAcnyk9A/6VISUjLUlNIt5NvdLN3auwkO9yFpGu7TVOuii9nKpXTd@Ri7MrAZ9/q4rUUbtZ2Uer7W8l50086qna@l6RdNpldkxt@QD8j/oCBlQkoWSCMydrCwt9CZCGIb4b7Bo@iYoNqmnJA8iIP2mQTflLKF7@JAATZ0TD46GOIohpAELsIiwTn29A3b6wc)

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZG7CsMwDEX3foUbSLAhAcnyk9A/6VISUjLUlNIt5NvdLN3auwkO9yFpGu7TVOuii9nKpXTd@Ri7MrAZ9/q4rUUbtZ2Uer7W8l50086qna@l6RdNpldkxt@QD8j/oCBlQkoWSCMydrCwt9CZCGIb4b7Bo@iYoNqmnJA8iIP2mQTflLKF7@JAATZ0TD46GOIohpAELsIiwTn29A3b6wc) by counting bits recursively.

Comment: @Arnauld Wow! That's down right diabolical - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda n:bin(n).count('1')%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU9LCsIwEN3nFLORNiAy@TQ/6EnURasUSzUtJS5EPHssZLp6M2/eh1k@6TFHlYf2kp/dq793EEM/xjry021@x1RXouIHmVP7ZYAB8MhABBAbqLK5sglFaAutSdxI4hFpkJb8pikS64iRzrtCGaXp6FHtDeglVQuDhjxaYGM1STRaY5yiEKGU0Vo0uEul195Y6Sn6x4Z5hQnGCCkwWNZx@3eoJ35M5@nK8x8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h!`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¤ä^
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWgh&code=pORe&input=NDI5NDk2NzI5NQ)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 18 bytes

Port of [ovs' Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199331/58974) - be sure to `+1` that if you're `+1`ing this.

```
f=n=>n&&n&1^f(n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtZDoIwEECv4hehYcROl2lrAhdxSQmCgWBLxBhuX@vvW@bu2239e1o/xxAfQ0pjE5o2FEUo8D6W4SRY6mPY4jLUS3yWFw4IEiygBDSgOGgByDMVBiRpMNaAsM4CSaXBcZlT7gQCEqc8INdG2TwaIvuXUpJSqHl2wilHRjh9q1/dWu5Nu1f@fPDVWO6M1XOcgr8Gz9IP)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 39 bytes

```php
for(;$n=&$argn;$n/=2)$p+=$n|0;echo$p%2;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxV8mzVVBKL0vOALH1bI02VAm1blbwaA@vU5Ix8lQJVI@v//00MDUzNTSz@5ReUZObnFf/XdQMA)