# Create a triangle whose colors are determined by the bitsums of coordinates

Tags: code-golf, geometry, graphical-output, fractal

Write a program that, for any \$n\$, generates a triangle made of hexagons as shown, \$2^n\$ to a side. The colors are to be determined as follows.

We may give the triangle barycentric coordinates so that every hexagon is described by a triple \$(x,y,z)\$ with \$x+y+z=2^n-1\$. (The three corners will be \$(2^n-1,0,0)\$, \$(0,2^n-1,0)\$, and \$(0,0,2^n-1)\$.)

Let \$s_2(n)\$ refer to the number of 1s in the binary expansion of \$n\$. (This is sometimes called the *bitsum* or the *popcount* function.) If
$$s_2(x)+s_2(y)+s_3(z)\equiv n\pmod 2$$
then color the hexagon \$(x,y,z)\$ in a light color; otherwise, color it in a dark color. (These must be *colors*, not simply black and white.)

In your answer, I would appreciate seeing several example outputs, ideally including \$n=10\$.

This is my first post here, so I apologize if I misunderstand the rules somehow.
[image]

This is a code golf challenge, so shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Why is the LaTeX not working? EDIT: Thank you! @RydwolfPrograms

Comment: CGCC uses a backslash before the `$`, so it'll be `\$n\$`

Comment: For what it's worth, I do not know if this fractal has a name or if it has been studied before. If \$A_n\$ denotes the number of light cells connected to the edges, I believe they satisfy the recurrence relation \$A_{n+3}=3A_{n+2}+9A_{n+1}-24A_n\$.

Comment: The _total_ white squares at for $n$ should be \$\frac12T_{2^n}+2^{(3/2)n-1}\$ for even \$n\$ and \$\frac12T_{2^n}+\frac3{\sqrt8}\cdot2^{(3/2)n-1}\$ for odd \$n\$, where \$T_k:=\frac{k(k+1)}2\$ denotes the \$k\$th triangular number.

Comment: I tried finding either a formula or a recurrence for the size of the large connected component of dark cells in the center, and haven't managed. (Anther potentially interesting combinatorics question: how many blue clusters of each size are there?)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! Challenges on this side need to have an [objective scoring criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria). Is this a code golf challenge? If so, please add the [tag:code-golf] tag.

Comment: @alephalpha Are there posts here that _aren't_ a code golf challenge?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger There are other winning criteria like [tag:fastest-code]. [Here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/what-are-the-winning-criteria-i-can-use-for-my-challenge) is a full list.

Comment: @alephalpha I mean, personally all I care about is that people make something that works, but in the interest of making an objective score I might as well make it code golf.

Comment: On the assumption that this pattern doesn't have a name already, anyone wanna come up with a name for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 119 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att).

```
Graphics@Table[{Hue[Tr[ThueMorse@{x,y,s-x-y}+#+1]/2],RegularPolygon[{2x+y,√3y},{1,Pi/2},6]},{x,0,s=2^#-1},{y,0,s-x}]&
```

[image]

Comment: Ooh!
This also gets closest to a regular aspect ratio out of the ones so far, I think. [EDIT: The aspect ratio of the JavaScript one depends on if I view it on my phone or laptop, it seems.]
Who knew that Mathematica has a "Thue Morse" function ready to go?

Comment: `(Tr@ThueMorse@...+#+1)/2`->`Tr[ThueMorse@...+#+1]/2`

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger For my answer I just picked a value for `line-height` that I thought looked good by eye; feel free to alter it to get a better aspect ratio.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Well, you might expect _Math_ematica to have built-in mathematical functions. At least, more so than [animal recognition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71631/upgoat-or-downgoat/71680#71680).

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES<s>7</s>6), <s>191</s> <s>187</s> <s>180</s> <s>174</s> <s>172</s> <s>168</s> 152 bytes

```js
f=
n=>eval('s="<center style=line-height:.7>";for(i=-1;++i<1<<n;s+="<br>")for(j=i+1;j--;)s+=`<font color=#f${(g=n=>n?9-g(n&n-1):9)(i^j^i-j)}0>⬢</font>`')
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 max=10 onchange=o.innerHTML=f(+this.value)><div id=o style=font-size:5px>
```

Output format is HTML. Snippet limited to `n=10` because it triggers my browser's slow script warning if you go any higher. (But the output is too big for my screen anyway.) Edit: Saved <s>4</s>* 11 bytes by simplifying the parity calculation. Saved <s>6</s> <s>8</s> 23 bytes thanks to @Ausername. Saved <s>4</s>* 5 bytes thanks to @EzioMercer.

*crossed out 4 is still regular 4

Comment: Very nice! How does it check the bit parities?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger `n^i`, `j` and `i-j` are the barycentric coordinates, but to compare their parity with `n`, I `^` (XOR) everything together, and the `n^n` cancels out, leaving `i^j^i-j`. The result is converted to binary and pairs of `1`s are deleted. If any `1`s are left then you get red otherwise you get tan.

Comment: Depending on how far you're prepared to go, you could either add a `color=#` and use 3-digit hex codes b) use 2 or even 1-digit hex codes. Also, the font tag doesn't need to be closed.

Comment: You might also be able to ave some bytes by reversing the loops and using `j--` and similar as the condition, although that might need some rearanging

Comment: @emanresuA I don't really want to contemplate 522753 nested unclosed font tags. Also, I'm not sure that #990 is light enough to qualify as light. I originally did try having the loops descending but I didn't want to invert the triangle. On the other hand I have just seen an obvious 7 byte save after my previous edit.

Comment: Since the `j` loop is reversible, you can change it to `j=i+1;j--;`, also `color=#f${90*!+(i^j^i-j)...` works fine (orange and black)

Comment: Your code is 178 bytes not 180. And you can save 1 byte if move `j++` here `s+='<font color=${+(i^j^i-j++)`

Comment: You don't need the last semicolon, you can save 1 byte

Comment: @EzioMercer `⬢` is 3 bytes.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I counted the number of characters by mistake

Comment: You can use `eval` instead of `return` to save some bytes **eval('s="<center style=line-height:.7>";for(i=0;i<1<<n;s+="<br>",i++)for(j=0;j<=i;)s+=`<font color=${+(i^j^i-j++).toString(2).replace(/10*1/g,"")?"red":"tan"}>⬢</font>`;s')**

Comment: @emanresuA Black isn't allowed but I just moved the `0` of `90` after the `${...}` to give orange and red, thanks.

Comment: [172 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcxdagIxFIbhrdhYMHGcP6EUm59NeC@O8WQ8IeRIEoQibqbXXZUbGcfb7@F7/XAbsk14LXWkM0xOT1EbuA2Br7JmykIskBa5/AbQASPUF8DxUn6ab8Oko8RRdxJVr1SUuZofp2TYBqtKvNHP6JVG6edh5qNyFMvCUqCkl@7zvlt/VBwP/oC1F02hfUkYR74VTYJrGCzwtu/WfTtuGBOPzjz//1T7bpijzCsxWYqZAjSBRu74lxDTCw "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: [171 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcxbagIxFIDhrdhYMHGcm1CKzWUTvotjPBlPCDmSBKGIm@lzV@VGxvH54//9cBuyTXgtdaQzTE5PURu4DYGvsmbKQiyQFrn8BtABI9QXwPFSfppvw6SjxFF3ElWvVJS5motTMmyDVSXe6Gf0SqMUsx2Vo1gWlgIlvXSf9936o@J48Aes/Rw0hfYlYRz5VjQJrmGwwNu@W/ftuGFMPDrz/P9T7ftijjKvxGQpZgrQBBq5419CTC8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: [170 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcxbagIxFIDhrWgqmBgzl4JIm8sm@i5O05PxhJAjSRBK6Wb63FV1I1N9/vj/ON2m6gtem8r0AUuwS7YOblPi22qZ8ZAblFVtnwlswgzqAjhf2mt3dEwHKhztoNGMxmRd5b14L47tUUrxwGhRjjoqpcUdzyZQbitPiYp9Cpuvl91acjzFE6ooukZvrWCe@bPoClzT5IH347Ab@3nPmPge3N/vj@kfD3fWdSsWT7lSgi7RzAM/CLH8Aw "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @EzioMercer You don't need the `;s`

Comment: @emanresuA Yes, you are right! [168 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcxbagIxFIDhrWgqmBgzl4JIm8sm@i5O05PxhJAjSRBK6Wb63FV1I1N9/vj/ON2m6gtem8r0AUuwS7YOblPi22qZ8ZAblFVtnwlswgzqAjhf2mt3dEwHKhztoNGMxmRd5b14L47tUUrxwGhRjjoqpcUdzyZQbitPiYp9Cpuvl91acjzFE6ooukZvrWCe@bPoClzT5IH347Ab@3nPmPge3N/vj@kfD3feisVTrpSgSzTzwA9CLP8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: Also I can't understand why you write `center` tag in your code if it is possible to write it in `html`? **HTML** - `<input type=number min=0 max=10 onchange=c.innerHTML=f(+this.value)><div style=font-size:5px><center id=c style=line-height:.7>`. **JS (without f=)** - **n=>eval('s="";for(i=0;i<1<<n;s+="<br>",i++)for(j=i+1;j--;)s+=`<font size="1px" color=#f${9*!+(i^j^i-j).toString(2).replace(/10*1/g,"")}0>⬢</font>`')**. This is 150 bytes

Comment: @EzioMercer Because the centre is a necessary effect for proper display of the output but the font size that I put on the div is just there to make it easier to see the larger outputs.

Comment: Oh, okay, you are right! Then you can use `eval` to reduce bytes count

Comment: 167 bytes - **n=>eval('s="<center style=line-height:.7>";for(i=-1;i++<1<<n;s+="<br>")for(j=i+1;j--;)s+=`<font color=#f${9*!+(i^j^i-j).toString(2).replace(/10*1/g,"")}0>⬢</font>`')**

Comment: @EzioMercer That loops too many times. Did you mean `++i<1<<n`?

Comment: [153](https://tio.run/##FY3RCsIgFEB/ZaxoirjqIaL02p@MraVLkWuoBBH1MT33Vf3I2l7P4XBcd@9SH@0tcwwXPRoYEZS@d55UCUrZa8w6Fik/vAZvUfOrtsM1H@u9KoUJkVjgW8GYlVspUSQ2ReeoSjo7BxvhJFhBJ95KEzAXffAhwsIsn2SA6YWnAx8Irt4c6fFAiW1cY7ljjL426vf9yPWcqbaiYx8wBa9rHwZiyI7S8Q8) by [adapting Arnauld's bit parity check](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169732/100664) (146 if you remove the </font>)

Comment: Yes, yes, sorry :)

Comment: [Actually make that 152](https://tio.run/##FY3RCsIgFEB/JVaUIq7tIaL02p@M1tKlyDVUBhHtY3ruq/qRtV7P4XBcO7Spi/aeOYarngxMCEoPrSebBIXsNGYdFyk/vAZvUfObtv0tH8u9KoQJkVjgtWDMylpKFInN0SWqgv6dg0o4CVbQmZ@lCZgXXfAhwtKsnqSH@YWnsSe4HjnS44ES27jGcscYfVXq@3nL7b9S5w2duoApeF360BNDdpROPw)

Comment: [132](https://tio.run/##FY1BDoIwEAC/ohykm6ZEDsaEtvgQIwGxQJtma9qGxIt/0TOv4iMVrzOZjOnmLvRePyND91BpkAllrebOkjzITPQKo/K7EF9WSatRsUnpcYpVca4zPjhPtGQlp1SLUgjkgW7R3dcZ/J2RR26E1Bw23q7Ld10@7ZWMcnvghe5Hgoc3Q6hKILoxjWaGUrjlkHqHwVlVWDeSgZwA0g8) but stretching the output format

Answer (score 5):

## C++ using SFML : <s>722</s> <s>703</s> <s>683</s> <s>527</s> <s>411</s> 399 bytes

-19 bytes thanks to NoLongerBreathedIn, using __builtin_popcount removes needing a bitsum function. Might work only for GCC.

-20 bytes, I used the using keyword for namespaces and components, and stopped using `.f` for magic numbers

-156 bytes thanks to pan

-116 bytes again thanks to pan

-12 bytes thanks to ceilingcat and pan

pan's proposed version approximates the value of cos(210) to around -.86, which will produce a slightly different graphic output, but very close to what's required by the challenge. This makes the cmath include useless. He also put the whole code into one function, and used a number of golfy techniques to reduce more the byte count, which makes the result very nice. His second optimization renders the use of vector useless, making an include and object usage useless

pan's code :

```cpp
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#define B+__builtin_popcount(
void v(int n){sf::CircleShape h(4,6);for(sf::RenderWindow w({1200,1000},"");w.isOpen();w.display()){for(sf::Event e;w.pollEvent(e);)e.type?h.setOrigin(-600,-650):w.close();w.clear();for(int x=0,y,z=1<<n;x<z;)for(y=x++-z;y++;)h.setPosition(4.3*(2*y+z-x),2.5*(2+z-3*x)),h.setFillColor(sf::Color(B-x)B-y)B z+y-x)-n&1?65535:-65281)),w.draw(h);}}
```

[SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) is a library that helps with the development of graphical / audio / network applications.

Previous 683 bytes answer (with the "exact" value or cos(210°)) :

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#define B(c) __builtin_popcount(c)
using namespace sf;struct t{double x,y;bool b;};using V=std::vector<t>;V d(int n){double r=5;int x,y,z,w=pow(2,n);V o;for(x=0;x<w;++x)for(y=0;y<w-x;++y){z=w-1-x-y;o.push_back({-cos(7*M_PI/6)*(r*y-r*z),r*x-(r*y+r*z)/2,(B(x)+B(y)+B(z))%2==n%2});}return o;}int v(int n){RenderWindow w(VideoMode(1200,1000),"");CircleShape h(4,6);;auto v=d(n);while(w.isOpen()){Event event;while(w.pollEvent(event))if(event.type==Event::Closed)w.close();w.clear();for(auto&a:v){h.setPosition(a.x,-a.y);h.setOrigin(-600,-650);h.setFillColor(a.b?Color::Yellow:Color::Blue);w.draw(h);}w.display();}return 0;}
```

Function to call in the main is `v(int)` with the parameter being n, the number `n`

```cpp
int main() {
    return v(6);
}
```

Compile with : `g++ source.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

Run with : `./a.out`

Due to the screen size and the fact that hexagons have to be visible, the size of a n=10 triangle can't be seen fully in a 'normal' sized screen, triangle is fully visible in the screen at n<=7. Size of hexagon and space between them can be configured in the `d(int)` function with variable `r` and `v(int)` function by modifying the first parameter of the constructor of the `h` variable (the CircleShape object), that value being the radius of the circle. Be free to modify those parameters to draw bigger hexagons on the screens, `r` should be slightly bigger that the circle's radius

Here is an image of the result for `n=6`

[image: Triangle for N=6]

Comment: Would using `__builtin_popcount` shorten the code?

Comment: [527](https://tio.run/##PVFdb9sgFH3Pr/A6qYIEqJ3NUWWcTkq17mVTp/Vhb4sIJjUaA4TxB7H82zOcdHtA4pxz7z1H93Jr8Svn5/N7qblqK1F2gnvjHhb/iZenb1/vvjhma8kbUlsbtUocpRbJbrXfH1qpvNR7ayw3rfaLxruW@8SPlWkPSiQDClRqnxzoRDsjq6QDM9RwbI5F8SgdV@KlZlYkNfiINpA2viqKa4zSP3SUtd4kbpsTejTu0jtsUxTQCfXbrCw1HcqerlYDnOWwTWkoezxEJsDTtscZHnBAHbFtU@8PjP8GIyb3myVwy4Dd8gSRWw54RqsZ3a3RDgxwB0J8J/hLT/DiO4f9IXQl3E@pK9MnPRizdZqiLE3TCd3cQNoT2TxboQGkcPzX87kTMbGIojVKXRAQsUAewTtBfLAC9oQr0wgwT4jLYA5cLf0tKzpYk0b476aRXhoNGBkQZiRAdOGfnXyVGuBNDII3efpGP0mlHo16i3D9MXK4zT5t8vxDXsTS9X0GIepJ5VgP6tm6ko1VLETzaTrPa/7D4miYjIsk3iweZjGd/wI)

Comment: [411](https://tio.run/##NVBNb4JAEL37K6gmzSywFFBMI9AmmtpLG5t66K2GwiqTbHc3gCISfztd1B4m2dk38z4mVYru0rTrRihSvs9YtF6@vz28FonKMS2dXKmnwShjWxTMmFubzc8eeYVio6RK5V5Ug4PEzDgAisoQpC23s9kCi5SzdZ4oZuQwsack3MoCeuiTiYwVXygyWRs1tJ7vurbnuu7ZHg5JWDtYrhQTQELS/u@8HJjmZhpUkvNLB0wP4BbumFM1ipHaSbksGfQMWjop4CrZmzrGrt3Yp9iLIhEeLSs6haTHmtgNmyg@0WNIcqdk1YcssUIpYOKMTaC@2VgaJDb1ncCEsXmkPj0RYl@GVwXuUACdav90Gri37yVyvpD85vz6gjlomjk0ujQhbSyLfAty7z1Pg2AczPS6/@hp4trJiqSGvE@RYal40ugc53PXx/hNtBwx2oGhj60vOjh3fw)

Comment: [399](https://tio.run/##NZDLboMwEEX3fIWVSJUdHgUSUIVJIyVqummVqll0GVHjBEuubQEJL/Ht1JB2d0d35s6ZIUrZF0KGYc4E4deUxsf9@9vja56ojJHCyZR6NuYpPTNBwdY8nb6vjJdMnJRURF5FCY2bZCm4QSZKIFBXnKNox3LC6TFLFAUZXFkhwmeZw9H6pCKl@RcTqaxABTvPd13Lc123t2YzhCuHFQdFBRxlygrFkwYi1P2Pv9yoXkO1qSTnUwUpwog6ZaPoJnMKWh5ydmEC2qFOtsPARVHlEC4LOoVqsCSHd6ARuV67VmO1ay@OBa7jFqPRada1adotbkwToyn1QxasZFLAlbNcQH/RmK1dI8t3Al1pvVzUCFlT655xvpP8D/mutrp5azdoC1qz0doWD94mDIJlEGlG/8nTw/riPKlghnDfDyPbT6LvQKAzgP6vfqLRD78) building on @ceilingcat

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 222 bytes

```
n=6;c=Graphics[{#,Rotate[Polygon@CirclePoints@6,30Degree]},ImageSize->9]&;Column[Row/@TakeList[(Tr@DigitCount[#,2,1]~Mod~2&/@Reverse@Select[Range[0,h=2^n-1]~Tuples~3,Tr@#==h&])/.{1->c@Red,0->c@Blue},Range[2^n]],Center,.01]
```

[image]